# Multiple installed versions of git - centos

Tags: centos, git, version

I manually installed git 1.6 a year or two ago.
I noticed today that the 1.7 version is available in yum, and installed it (package git-all)
I now get the following output:

```
[root@ovz5197 ~]# git --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/git: No such file or directory
[root@ovz5197 ~]# which git
/usr/bin/git
[root@ovz5197 ~]# /usr/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.4.1
[root@ovz5197 ~]#
```

Any idea why the output of `which` seems to contradict the first line above?

Comment: I was tempted asking you for what your `$PATH` variable look like, but as `which git` is finding it, it should be ok. However, the reason might be in your `$PATH`?

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/git` show? And `file /usr/local/bin/git`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you had already run `git` from this instance of bash back when there was a `/usr/local/bin/git`, it's remembering the old location in a cache. Run `hash -r` to clear the cache. Each instance of bash has its own cache, so newly started instances of bash will look in the right place.

Otherwise, you evidently have a file `/usr/local/bin/git`, and it's executable, but it doesn't work because its loader is not present on the system. See [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found/13409) for a similar case.

Comment: Yes it must have been a cache - the behaviour is as expected now, thanks very much for explaining!