# Problem when installing “ia32-libs”

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, executable

I'm using x64 Ubuntu. A few months ago I accidentally messed up the groups/owners of all files on `/`, but managed to fix it using a VirtualBox install of Ubuntu.

Now I'm running into a problem that I think is related to that mistake. When I try to reinstall `ia32-libs` (Skype is having problems so I need to reinstall those libs) I get an error message:

> /var/lib/dpkg/info/ia32-libs.postinst: 40: /usr/lib32/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: Permission denied

`ls -al` /usr/lib32/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/` is this:

```
total 476
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 2011-09-24 17:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 53 root root 143360 2011-09-24 17:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     40 2011-09-24 04:44 2.10.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   9648 2011-04-05 00:40 gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders
```

I have tried to reinstall `gdk-pixbuff-2.0`, but it didn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `ldd /usr/lib32/gdk-pixbuf-2.0//gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders` and make sure every file is accounted for (the line must end with an address like `(0xf7789000)`). In particular, check the permissions on the [dynamic loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found/13409#13409) `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`. This is the only file in the lot that could cause that particular error message, but you may need to fix other permissions while you're at it.

```
chown root:root /lib*/*
chmod a+rx /lib*/ld-* /lib*/*/
chmod -R a+r /lib
```

Comment: AAA IT WORKED! :) When i run "ldd" first time (as su or normal user) command i get result "not a dynamic executable" but then i performed those "chown" commands you specified and then "ldd" worked as a charm AND ia32-libs GOT RE INSTALLED WITHOUT ERROR! :) THENK YOU KIND SIR :)