# When executable files aren't

Tags: executable, 64bit, elf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't execute some binaries in chroot environment (zsh: Not found)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found)

Today I ran into something that has me stumped. A co-worker is working with a specific pre-compiled binary he downloaded (available [here](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html)). On the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server he's working on, attempting to execute this file yields file-not-found, even with permissions set right.

And yet, when I attempt the same thing from OpenSUSE 11.4, it runs just fine. Running `file` on it gives me:

> ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

Both the Ubuntu and OpenSUSE boxes are 64-bit installs, and `file` returns the same information on both machines.

Which looks just fine to me. And on the opensuse box, LDD even gives me a short list of library files. Hand checking, all of those specified files also exist on the Ubuntu server. Strace output is different though:

Opensuse:

> execve("./trid", ["./trid"], [/* 122 vars */]) = 0

Ubuntu (giving full path does not change result):

> execve("./trid", ["./trid"], [/* 19 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

What can cause a file like this to not be executable in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
ldd ./trid
```

both on the openSuse and Ubuntu system.

I suspect you'll find that the latter is missing a library file.

Comment: That was my first guess. `ldd` on Ubuntu doesn't give anything terribly useful. Just "File is not a dynamic executable".

Comment: Sounds like the Ubuntu install somehow doesn't know what to do with 32-bit software. Which is odd since last time I checked x86-compatibility libraries were part of amd64's base files.

Comment: Turns out the `libc6-i386` package wasn't installed. This instance was a 'minimal server' install, so lacked some packages.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it.