# File does exist but won't execute

Tags: linux, executable

I have a file that does exist but won't execute. It says : "No such file or directory".

This file is created by a script while creating a "custom toolchain" to compile native libraries for Android using the NDK.

I'm certain that the file exists where I beleive it exists. Also `file` says : `arm-linux-androideabi-g++: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped`

I tried running as root, I also tried applying `chmod 777`, but nothing helped.

The file is located at : `/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++`

It won't run even if I specify a full path, even if I copy it somewhere else (like in my home folder).

`ldd` says it's not a dynamic executable.

Maybe that this file is just a .so and not an actual executable with an entry point ?

I'm using Ubuntu 14, 64 bit, in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the comments of this question : [When executable files aren't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/when-executable-files-arent?rq=1)

It was a 32 / 64 bit problem.

[When executable files aren't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/when-executable-files-arent?rq=1)

fixed it.