# Arch Linux 64bit Android ADB?

Tags: arch-linux, 64bit, android

I am trying to use the Android SDK on Arch Linux 64bit but when I try to run ADB from the correct dirrectory it says the file does not exist, but it is there. On Ubuntu when you have this problem you install ia32-lib but there is none in Arch Linux. Is there something I have to do.

Comment: Have you enabled [multilib]?

Comment: No I have not, though if I do, what would I need from it?

Comment: Oh these worked thanks!


lib32-libstdc++5
lib32-libx11
lib32-ncurses
lib32-zlib
lib32-sdl
lib32-libxext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “no such file or directory” message is in fact referring to the loader for 32-bit executables, which is needed to execute your 32-bit executable. For a more detailed explanation, see [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found). You need to install 32-bit support on your Arch Linux.

Unfortunately, Arch Linux doesn't have a simple way of installing 32-bit support. At the moment, you need to enable the [multilib] repository by adding these lines to `pacman.conf`:

```
[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

See the [Arch64 FAQ](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch64_FAQ#Can_I_run_32-bit_apps_inside_Arch64.3F) and [Using 32-bit-applications on Arch64](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Using_32-bit-applications_on_Arch64) on the wiki for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For me, with a reasonably fresh ArchLinux install (November 2015), I had to uncomment the "multilib" section in my /etc/pacman.conf as @gilles suggests.

Further, I had to use pacman to install the required packages like so:

`sudo pacman -S lib32-ncurses lib32-zlib lib32-libstdc++5`

After this, `adb`, `fastboot` and related development utilities like `mksdcard` all worked just fine on my 64-bit Intel system.