# Cannot execute binaries in Ubuntu : file not found

Tags: ubuntu, console, executable

When I try to run any executable file a `file not found` error occurs. Sometimes it says nothing but doesn't do anything.

For example, when I execute `./blah-blah.bin` it fails finding the file when it is clearly there. When I execute `./blah-blah-file-2.sh`, it is silent.

Note 1: files have +x.
Note 2: root also cannot execute.
Note 3: everything from /usr/bin executes.
Note 4: I can't try it from GUI, I have only access to its console.

What's the problem?

Upd: suddenly some commands (e.g. `ls`) begin fail with a `file not found`. They worked yesterday...

Comment: Please post the first couple of lines of that file (I'm betting it doesn't contain the #! path to a valid shell).

Comment: The output of `file` is the better thing to ask for, as below.

Comment: `./alfresco-install.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped`

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be trying to execute a 32bit binary on a 64bit OS without 32bit support packages? Without the ia32 libs you wouldn't get very far on AMD64...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't execute some binaries in chroot environment (zsh: Not found)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found)

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
ldd ./alfresco-install.bin
```

and check the output. This sounds suspiciously like it's missing a dynamic library or two.

Comment: This solved my problem. I had the same issue where executing a file would just produce "not found" as if the file couldn't be found. Using this I found out that it was trying to load a library that didn't exists.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a script or a binary executable?

If it's a script, check the `#!` line.

Depending on your shell, the error message for a command with a bad `#!` line can refer to the script rather than to the missing interpreter.

For example, using tcsh:

```
% cat foo
#!/bin/no_such_interpreter

echo hello
% chmod +x foo
% ./foo
./foo: Command not found.
%
```

Using bash, the error message is different:

```
$ chmod +x foo
$ cat foo
#!/bin/no_such_interpreter

echo hello
$ ./foo
bash: ./foo: /bin/no_such_interpreter: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
$
```

Even if the `#!` line *looks* ok, it can fail if there's a `\r` character at the end of the line, which can often happen if the file was created on Windows.  What does

```
head -1 blah-blah.bin | cat -A
```

show you?

If that doesn't solve the problem, show us *exactly* what command you typed and the error message that resulted.

**EDIT :** I realize your title suggests it's a binary executable.  Exactly what kind of file is it?  What is the output of

```
file blah-blah.bin
```

?

Comment: The script installs from binary. I can execute that binary and script everywhere except one conctrete linux.

Comment: _Even if the `#!` line looks ok, it can fail if there's a `\r` character at the end of the line_ +1 I fell into this trap, just now, again (happens way too often)

Comment: CRLF. Yup. It bit me too.

Answer (score 1):

Check the mount options, specifically, whether it is mounted noexec.

If this is the problem, e.g. on /tmp, do

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

Comment: `mount: /tmp is not mounted or invalid option`

Comment: @Alexey: ahem. <spelling-it-out> `e.g.` means 'for example'. You need, of course, to inspect the mount point that _contains your binary_). I think `df .` in that directory will help

Comment: To just list all mounts, enter... `mount`

Comment: a `noexec` mount would fail with `operation not permitted` rather than file not found.