# Problem with executing Firefox version 9.0.1

Tags: linux, debian, executable, firefox, 64bit

I cannot run firefox version 9.0.1. When i try to execute the binary `firefox` I get an error `-bash: ./firefox: cannot execute binary file`. The info returned by `file` is as follows:

```
firefox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

The system info returned by `uname -r` is:

```
2.6.37
```

It might be worth mentioning that I do not have administrator rights on this machine (I have a shell account).

I am downloading the file from the following web page: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html (file name `firefox-9.0.1.tar.bz2`)

Then I am extracting the file into my home folder using `tar xvf firefox-9.0.1.tar.bz2`.
Then I go into the `firefox` directory and try to execute by typing `./firefox`. After that I get the aforementioned error.

The file `firefox` of course have the rights to be executed (`x`).

Does anyone have any idea why I cannot execute the browser?

Comment: Can you show the output of `ldd ./firefox`, and `readelf -a ./firefox|grep Requesting`?

Comment: The output of `ldd ./firefox` shows this `/usr/bin/ldd: line 161: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: cannot execute binary file not a dynamic executable`. The second one shows `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]`.

Comment: I have found one more thing. It looks like the server I operate on is a 64 bit system. The `uname -mr` returns `2.6.37 x86_64`. Right now I am looking for a 64 bit Firefox binaries. I will let you know whether it solves the problem.

Comment: You appear to be running a 64bit distro that doesn't have 32bit support installed. I don't know how Debian does its 32bit support, so sorry, can't help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't execute some binaries in chroot environment (zsh: Not found)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was indeed the fact that the system is 64 bit and does not have the support for executing 32 bit binaries installed.

I downloaded the newest version of Firefox for x64 architecture from [Firefox 9.0.1 x86_64](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/9.0.1/linux-x86_64)