# skype not found on Oneiric 64, but it is right there

Tags: shell, filesystems, executable, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't execute some binaries in chroot environment (zsh: Not found)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found)

I have something weird here. Cannot find a file although it is right there.

```
$ skype
command not found: skype
$ whereis skype
skype: /usr/bin/skype /usr/share/skype
$ /usr/bin/skype
file or directory not found: /usr/bin/skype
$ ls -l /usr/bin/skype
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21362968 2011-06-08 12:26 /usr/bin/skype
$ type /usr/bin/skype
/usr/bin/skype is /usr/bin/skype
$ which skype
/usr/bin/skype
```

Any explanation for that? Happened only with skype so far, no matter if on zsh or bash. I'm on Ubuntu Natty 64, had not encountered anything like that before.

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /usr/bin/skype`? And why do you think that the `type` output is weird? That looks right to me. You might be thinking of `file`.

Comment: @johann have you tried `file` and `which` ?

Comment: @ChrisDown
    `$ file /usr/bin/skype`
    `/usr/bin/skype: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped`

Comment: @ChrisDown `$ ldd /usr/bin/skype`
 `the program is not dynamically linked`
looks okay. but could it be that there's an issue with 32bit libraries, since I am on 64, just checking if the 32libs are there (shouldn't apt take care of that?)

Comment: did this just begin happening and skype was previously working?
You're on 64 bit linux and Skype is 32bit, have you installed the ia32-libs package? Since skype is dynamically linked it needs to find the underlying libs. You could try the skype 2.2 linux beta, I believe it has more statically linked libs.

Comment: it just worked until today. I think there's something broken with the ia32-libs packages, I just found something on http://www.mindwerks.net/2011/09/skype-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/ and  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/830440

Answer (score 1):

The error messages provided where a bit misleading. In fact, it was an issue with the ia32-libs package. I followed some steps on these web pages:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/830440
http://www.mindwerks.net/2011/09/skype-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Namely, installing a few more 32-bit packages helped:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 \
libqtgui4:i386
```

Comment: so shall I reformat my previous comment as an answer for you?

Comment: you could :-) although I am not even sure if my question is not a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found

Comment: This just happened to me as well when installing Unreal Tournament. I really wish bash (or it's dependencies) would just give an "invalid executable format" error or something a bit more descriptive. Everybody asks this question with a different program at fault (skype, unreal tournament, etc) and it's a configuration issue of missing libraries.