# "No such file or directory" when I clearly see the file listed with correct permissions

Tags: bash, executable, 64bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting “Not found” message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)

Ok I feel like I'm having some sort of brain fade moment, please help me out.

I just installed Unreal Tournament on my Linux Mint Debian Edition OS. The startup script was complaining about a missing file so I decided to check it out manually.

```
~/Desktop $ ut
/usr/local/bin/ut: 78: ./ut-bin: not found
~/Desktop $ cd /usr/local/games/ut/System/
/usr/local/games/ut/System $ ls -l ut-bin 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root staff 91336 Jan 28 11:33 ut-bin
/usr/local/games/ut/System $ ./ut-bin 
bash: ./ut-bin: No such file or directory
```

`ut-bin` is a binary executable according to the `file` command. Why is bash complaining about a missing file? I tried executing it in another shell and got a similar error. I also launched a new terminal with no change.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Similar question yesterday](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30063/skype-not-found-on-oneiric-64-but-it-is-right-there), missing ia-32 libs.

Comment: I installed the ia32-libs package and it now executes. Couldn't bash return something like "invalid executable format"? I knew this had to be something stupid, like missing 32-bit libraries on new system install, but what a terrible error message for this situation.

Comment: @Mr.Shickadance: Actually, `bash` can't do anything about it (except guessing, which would be even worse). On Linux, execve(2) returns `ENOENT` when _the file filename or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist, or a shared library needed for file or interpreter cannot be found._ So the proper place to fix this would be the execve system call, not bash.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained, it happened because of missing 32-bit libraries.
As a followup, if you encounter the problem, you might want to have a look at the output of file:

```
runejuhl@lapaz:~/opt/maple/maple15/bin.X86_64_LINUX$ file cmaple 
cmaple: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, stripped
runejuhl@lapaz:~/opt/maple/maple15/bin.X86_64_LINUX$ file lmutilv95 
lmutilv95: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped
```

From the output above, it's apparent that the former executable is built for a 64-bit system, while the latter is built for an x86 system.