# How to install & run collectd on Solaris 10 x86

Tags: software-installation, solaris

I am trying to install and run [`collectd`](http://collectd.org) on Solaris 10 x86. I downloaded the Solaris x86 version of the installer. Installed using `pkd_add` command and chose the default folders.

Now I am trying to run the daemon, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the problem / error:

```
bash-3.00# sbin/collectd
bash: sbin/collectd: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: have you checked if you have 'x' rights on sbin/collectd ?

Comment: Yes, I have 'x' rights for sbin and collectd

Comment: What does `file sbin/collectd` yield?  This error typically comes from using a binary made for another platform (SPARC vs x86, Solaris vs Linux, MacOS vs Linux).

Comment: @lars-rohrbach Here is what I get: `sbin/collectd:  ELF 64-bit LSB executable AMD64 Version 1 [SSE2 SSE FXSR FPU], dynamically linked, not stripped`

Comment: See also [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13391) You have an executable format that your kernel doesn't support.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your output from `file sbin/collectd`, you are attempting to execute a binary for AMD64 (also known as x86_64), which I see the collectd website offers in package form for Solaris 10.  This will only work on x86_64, not on i386.  I suspect that you have i386 (you can double-check with `uname -p` or `uname -a`).

Since the collectd folks aren't offering a ready-to-go package for Solaris 10 x86, it seems, the only option would be to compile it from source.

Do you have SUNWspro installed for the Sun `cc` compiler?  I ran into difficulty trying to compile collectd with gcc on Solaris 10 x86, but Sun's `cc` worked like this:

```
wget http://collectd.org/files/collectd-5.0.3.tar.bz2
gtar xjf collectd-5.0.3.tar.bz2
cd collectd-5.0.3
./configure CC=/path/to/cc CFLAGS="-m64 -mt -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS"
make && make install
```

Comment: `isainfo -v` is the Solaris command to determine support for 32-bit/64-bit binaries.