# What does "Invalid argument" mean in Solaris?

Tags: command-line, solaris

```
-bash-3.00$ ./p4 -V
-bash: ./p4: Invalid argument
```

What does "Invalid argument" mean in Unix?

**More details:**

1. p4 is an executable in the current directory.
2. p4 actually refers to perforce. The option -V is supposed to display the version details.
3. Solaris 10 is the OS.
4. p4 has executable permissions (chmod +x p4)
5. The official documentation wasn't very helpful in my case.

Comment: I figured it out!

I was running an x86 binary on a sparc machine.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/9436882/640378

On Solaris, when you try running a SPARC binary on an x86 platform (or vice versa), "Invalid argument" is the error you get.

Comment: I swear this is a duplicate, but I can't find it. In any case, you should post that as an answer when you can (should be available after 8 hours)

Comment: This is the same issue as [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13391); Solaris has a different error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out!

**I was running an x86 binary on a SPARC machine.**

[Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436882/640378)

On Solaris, when you try running a SPARC binary on an x86 platform (or vice versa), `Invalid argument` is the error you get.