# executing binary file: file not found

Tags: ubuntu, files, compiling, binary, patchelf

I know there are similar questions out there, but I haven't found a solution nor this exact case. The binary was built on Arch Linux using its GCC 4.7. The package works fine on the build system. The commands below were executed on:

> Linux vbox-ubuntu 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The file in question is located [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.7-release/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.7.1-1-release-linux64_rubenvb.tar.xz/download). It's a Linux 64-bit to Windows 64-bit cross-compiler. Untarring it to `~/` gives a single `~/mingw64` directory which contains everything needed.

When I try to run `~/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as` this is what I get:

```
bash: /home/ruben/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as: No such file or directory
```

Running `file ~/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as` gives me:

```
/home/ruben/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0x0b8e50955e7919b76967bac042f49c5876804248, not stripped
```

Running `ldd ~/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as` gives me:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3e367000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2ceae7e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2ceaac1000)
    /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2ceb0a8000)
```

I am truly at a loss. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**: Some more details:
The build system is Arch Linux (currently glibc 2.16).
The output of `ls -l` is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 2 ruben users 1506464 11 aug 23:49 /home/ruben/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as
```

The output of `objdump -p` is:

```
Version References:
  required from libz.so.1:
    0x0827e5c0 0x00 05 ZLIB_1.2.0
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x0d696917 0x00 06 GLIBC_2.7
    0x06969194 0x00 04 GLIBC_2.14
    0x0d696913 0x00 03 GLIBC_2.3
    0x09691a75 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.2.5
```

The output of `ldd -v` on Ubuntu 12.04 is:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff225ff000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd525c71000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd5258b4000)
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd525e9b000)

Version information:
/home/ruben/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as:
    libz.so.1 (ZLIB_1.2.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1:
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

The tested other OSes are Fedora 17 (glibc 2.15) and Ubuntu 12.04 (eglibc 2.15). Both zlib and glibc version requirements are met.

Comment: is it just a typo or are you actually trying to run '~/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/as' ... it's missing the 'bin' folder.

Comment: @tripledes type, and corrected.

Comment: weird, just tried to download, untar under my ~ and I get the exptected result. Could you provide an ls -l ~/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as ?

Comment: Could it be a libc version mismatch? Try running "objdump -p <path/to/as>" and inspect the "Version References" section. It could look like it depends on GLIBC_2.14, which could be considered fairly new. What's your system version? "readelf -a <path/to/as>|less" and grep for GLIBC, you'll see that it's using memcpy from 2.14. I don't know why the version would vary so much between different library calls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I run `ldd -v as` on my system, I get:

```
./as: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./as)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff89ab1000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1e4c81f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1e4c498000)
        /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1e4ca6d000)
```

So yeah, it looks like these binaries are looking for a `GLIBC_2.14` symbol, which you are presumably missing on your system.  As svenx pointed out, it looks like it's searching for the `memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14` symbol.  Some more information on why `memcpy` was given a new version is described [in this bug report](http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12518).

Installing a new version of `glibc` on your target system should fix it.  If you want to try to rebuild the binary to still work on the old version of `glibc`, you could try tricks like the one listed [here](http://rjpower.org/wordpress/fun-with-shared-libraries-version-glibc_2-14-not-found/).  You could also maybe get by with a shim that just provides the specific version of the `memcpy` symbol that you need, but that gets to be a bit hacky.

---

**After reading your update**: you're right, that wasn't your problem.  But I think I've found it: your binary is requesting the interpreter `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, which doesn't exist on Ubuntu 12.04 systems:

```
$ readelf -a ./as | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

While `ldd` knew to find it in `/lib64` instead, I suppose the kernel doesn't know that when it tries to run the binary and can't find the file's requested interpreter.  You could try just running it through the interpreter manually:

```
$ pwd
/home/jim/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin
$ ./as --version
-bash: ./as: No such file or directory
$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./as --version
GNU assembler (rubenvb-4.7.1-1-release) 2.23.51.20120808
Copyright 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-w64-mingw32'.
```

I'm not 100% certain this is working correctly -- on my system, running `gcc` this way gives a segmentation fault.  But that's at least a different problem.

Comment: That would have been nice, if this was the case. See update `:(`

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, ok. This kind of sucks. I can't think of a decent way to work around this problem (and keep building on Arch). Do you have any brilliant ideas?

Comment: Not really.  Arch is just being stupid -- the [Filesystem Heirarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#LIB64) clearly says that libraries should be in `/lib64` on amd64, and apparently Arch manually patches their gcc sources to change this, thereby **guaranteeing** incompatibility with every other Linux distribution out there.  See the comments of [this bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/24271) for their bizarre reasoning.  To me, this would be a clear warning sign to stay away from Arch Linux.

Comment: That said, you can change the interpreter location using [patchelf](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html).  See [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1063429) for another person running into this problem, who claimed that `patchelf` worked for them.

Comment: I have submitted a reopen request to the Arch bug tracker. This modification is IMHO against Arch philosophy by design, and as we both know, very much incompatible with vanilla Linux/glibc/GCC installs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a variant of [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system/13409#13409): you have an executable that mentions a dynamic loader that is not there.

In your case, the dynamic loader `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` exists but in a different location `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. The simplest way to make your programs work would be to create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s ../lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib/
```

Comment: well, as this is a package meant for redistributing, such a symlink is not really in my control. I thought Linux binaries would be more portable... guess not.