# Command & binary exists but cannot be executed

Tags: debian, apt, command

I transfered `/etc/*` files from one Linux server to another and now I have a strange error. Both are Debian Squeeze.

When I run a command, e.g. `ssh`, I get an error:

> bash: /usr/bin/ssh: No such file or directory

It looks like the binary exists:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 358756 Sep 21 14:30 /usr/bin/ssh

Bash also autocompletes the command when I type `ss` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I tried reinstalling, purging etc but it didn't solve anything. There is probably something cached under `/etc/` but I don't know what excatly.

Comment: What's the output of `ldd /usr/bin/ssh`?  It might depend on a library (`.so` file) that doesn't exist.

Comment: @mrb the output is "not a dynamic executable".

Comment: How did you copy the files? What does `file /usr/bin/ssh` tell you?

Comment: @Mat Copied like this: `scp -r /etc/* user@remote:/etc/`
and the output of the "file" command is `/usr/bin/ssh: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped`

Comment: If that helps I also installed the same packages using `dpkg --set-selections` & `apt-get dselect-upgrade`.

Comment: So file says it uses shared libs, and `ldd` doesn't... something's screwed up. Try `readelf -l /usr/bin/ssh` and look for a "Requesting interpreter" line (or error).

Comment: @Mat `ldd` actually *runs* the program. So of course it doesn't work. (BTW: `ldd` is a shell script; `less \`which ldd\`` and you can see how it works)

Comment: @mrb Same comment about `ldd` actually running the program to you, too. Its important that people know this, less they try `ldd` when analyzing an untrusted binary.

Comment: @derobert: it doesn't actually run the program, it invokes the runtime linker and does pretty much all the runtime linking with debug options, but it doesn't invoke the program's main.

Comment: @Mat: `strace -f ldd \`which cat\` |& grep execve`: `… [pid  8490] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 46 vars */] <unfinished ...>`

Comment: @derobert: try `ldd /usr/bin/vi` or `ldd /sbin/halt` - this won't run vi or `halt`. The runtime linker gets debug options from the environment, set up from the `ldd` script, and stops short from actually running the code.

Comment: @Mat yes, the glibc start code (still part of the executable) doesn't invoke the program's main. But the point is that we know (from the error posted) that `execve` is failing. And so its not surprising that ldd does as well (as that `strace` shows, it actually does an `execve` of the program)

Comment: @derobert: I was reacting to your statement that `ldd` _runs_ the executable, which would make `ldd` bloody dangerous. We both agree, I think, that `ldd` not managing to list dependencies and `file` saying it is dynamically linked, is a problem, right?

Comment: Is the binary the same architecture as the rest of the userspace (i386)?

Comment: @Mat It is bloody dangerous to run on an executable you don't trust (see, e.g., http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), though some versions of ldd are patched against this. The disagreement is a problem, but (for example) is exactly what is expected (I just tested this) if the executable is the wrong architecture.

Comment: You *only* transferred `/etc`? Weird that it broke ssh, but ls still works. Were the two machines the same architecture (or at least running the same, i.e., both running i386)?

Comment: ldd doesn't call `_start`/`main` as normal when called on a normal dynamically-linked executable, but an executable _can_ be crafted to run arbitrary code on being examined with some versions of ldd.

Comment: @strangefishinthetown And what happens when you run `/usr/bin/ssh` (i.e. full path)?  Is the file actually executable?

Comment: @strangefishinthetown You might try removing `/etc/ld.so.cache` and checking the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.  Run `ldconfig` to rebuild the cache afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Jim Paris's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49393/command-binary-exists-but-cannot-be-executed#comment69116_49393) is right on the mark. You can get “no such file or directory” even if the specified file exists, if the dynamic loader for that file does not exist. A common case is trying to run a binary from a different architecture that the kernel supports but not the user-land system — typically a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system that doesn't have 32-bit libraries installed. See [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system) for a more detailed explanation of that case.

Here, it's possible that `/usr/bin/ssh` uses a library that is installed in a different place on the new system. Since you copied the dynamic linker's cache file `/etc/ld.so.cache`, the dynamic linker is looking for that library in a place where it doesn't exist. Run `ldconfig` to update the cache.

It's also possible that you'd enabled [prelinking](http://packages.debian.org/prelink). If so, remove `/etc/prelink.cache`.