# /bin/sh: ./check-dependencies.pl: not found — but check-dependencies.pl exists!

Tags: scripting, perl, executable, gnu-make

I'm trying to build [Moses](http://www.statmt.org/moses/), but when I run `make` I get the following output:

```
minakshi@minakshi-Vostro-3500:~/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts$ make release
# Compile the parts
make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts'
# Building memscore may fail e.g. if boost is not available.
# We ignore this because traditional scoring will still work and memscore isn't used by default.
cd training/memscore ; \
      ./configure && make \
      || ( echo "WARNING: Building memscore failed."; \
           echo 'training/memscore/memscore' >> ../../release-exclude )
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for boostlib >= 1.31.0... yes
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for gzopen in -lz... yes
checking for cblas_dgemm in -lgslcblas... no
checking for gsl_blas_dgemm in -lgsl... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking n_gram.h usability... no
checking n_gram.h presence... no
checking for n_gram.h... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/memscore'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/memscore'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/memscore'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/memscore'
touch release-exclude # No files excluded by default
pwd=`pwd`; \
    for subdir in cmert-0.5 phrase-extract symal mbr lexical-reordering; do \
      make -C training/$subdir || exit 1; \
      echo "### Compiler $subdir"; \
      cd $pwd; \
    done
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/cmert-0.5'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/cmert-0.5'
### Compiler cmert-0.5
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/phrase-extract'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/phrase-extract'
### Compiler phrase-extract
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/symal'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/symal'
### Compiler symal
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/mbr'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/mbr'
### Compiler mbr
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/lexical-reordering'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/lexical-reordering'
### Compiler lexical-reordering
## All files that need compilation were compiled
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts'
/bin/sh: ./check-dependencies.pl: Permission denied
make: *** [release] Error 126
minakshi@minakshi-Vostro-3500:~/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts$ make release
# Compile the parts
make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts'
# Building memscore may fail e.g. if boost is not available.
# We ignore this because traditional scoring will still work and memscore isn't used by default.
cd training/memscore ; \
      ./configure && make \
      || ( echo "WARNING: Building memscore failed."; \
           echo 'training/memscore/memscore' >> ../../release-exclude )
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for boostlib >= 1.31.0... yes
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for gzopen in -lz... yes
checking for cblas_dgemm in -lgslcblas... no
checking for gsl_blas_dgemm in -lgsl... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking n_gram.h usability... no
checking n_gram.h presence... no
checking for n_gram.h... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/memscore'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/memscore'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/memscore'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/memscore'
touch release-exclude # No files excluded by default
pwd=`pwd`; \
    for subdir in cmert-0.5 phrase-extract symal mbr lexical-reordering; do \
      make -C training/$subdir || exit 1; \
      echo "### Compiler $subdir"; \
      cd $pwd; \
    done
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/cmert-0.5'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/cmert-0.5'
### Compiler cmert-0.5
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/phrase-extract'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/phrase-extract'
### Compiler phrase-extract
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/symal'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/symal'
### Compiler symal
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/mbr'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/mbr'
### Compiler mbr
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/lexical-reordering'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts/training/lexical-reordering'
### Compiler lexical-reordering
## All files that need compilation were compiled
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts'
/bin/sh: ./check-dependencies.pl: not found
make: *** [release] Error 127
```

The error message says `./check-dependencies.pl` is "not found", but I see the file present in the `scripts` folder. So why does this error occur?

Comment: `./check-dependencies.pl` is a relative path - maybe `make` is in another directory when trying to access it? It says it's leaving the `scripts` dir just before, in case the script is located there.

Comment: Your question has been downvoted and closed because you didn't provide much information, in particular you didn't say what program you're trying to compile or on what system. I voted to close too, though on second thoughts I think I shouldn't have (and I voted to reopen), because I suspect that I've guessed what's going wrong. Really, you should provide more information. (Copy-pasting the whole transcript from the make session was good though.)

Comment: If this is not a private project, you can make a tar ball and let us see the problem

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason for this error is that `check-dependencies.pl` is not in the directory where the makefile looks for it. However, if the file `check-dependencies.pl` does exist in `/home/minakshi/Desktop/working-dir/moses/scripts`, then there's another possibility: maybe its loader doesn't exist.

- For a script, the loader is the interpreter mentioned in the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line, i.e. the first line, which must begin with `#!` followed by the path to the interpreter.
- For a binary, the loader is the [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (statically linked executables don't have a loader) — see [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system/13409#13409).

When the kernel is told to execute a program, it executes the loader program and passes it the executable to load. If the loader is not found, the kernel can only report “not found”, it doesn't have a way to distinguish “directly requested file not found” from “loader not found”. Sometimes the executing shell will make a second check to display a more explicit error message, but sometimes you end up with a strange-looking message that tells you that a script or dynamically-linked executable is not found or not executable, when in fact the file does exist and is executable but the error applies to its loader.

With a `.pl` extension, `check-dependencies.pl` is presumably a Perl script. It probably starts with a line like `#!/usr/local/bin/perl`, which doesn't give the path to the perl interpreter on your system. Edit the script and fix the first line; you'll probably have to replace `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` by `#!/usr/bin/perl` or vice versa.

Perl is usually located in `/usr/bin` on Linux, but in `/usr/local/bin` on many other unices. There's a way to write the shebang line without knowing the path to the interpreter in advance: `#!/usr/bin/env perl`. The shebang line requires an absolute path; here the interpreter is `env` which looks up `perl` in the `$PATH`. However this only works if there are no arguments to pass to the interpreter: many systems, including Linux, accept a single argument on the command line, so e.g. `#!/usr/bin/perl -T` works, and `#!/usr/bin/env perl` works, but `#!/usr/bin/env perl -T` fails because it tries to execute a program called `perl -T`.