# Can't execute a file with execute permission bit set

Tags: permissions, mount, executable

Well I'm just too green to Linux, but I'm stuck with a thing that I should know, and I don't.
My file has the following permission bits sets:

```
-r-xr-xr-x
```

is owned by `root` ( but it should not matter since `-x` is active even for any user) it is not writable, and since it resides on a CDROM even if is a virtual iso mounted as a cdrom it sounds ok, but I can't execute:
It says "Permission Denied"
What I miss? The mount itself has execution permission, so it should execute, why it does not?

**EDIT**

I solved the issue, but not my doubt, since expliciting `bash ./autorun.sh`  works - i need a `root` account anyway for what's inside, but it works.

Comment: Where is it mounted to exactly? Perhaps it needs write access to perform a task, it would help to know something about the app.

Comment: was automounted by virtualbox, it is part of the "Guest Additions"

Comment: Since it's a cdrom and an automount, it's likely mounted with the `noexec` option. This prevents anything from being executed from that filesystem. You can disable the `noexec` option by remounting with `mount -o remount,exec /path/to/mount`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most likely explanation is [Patrick's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102812/cant-execute-a-file-with-execute-permission-bit-set#comment157140_102812): the filesystem is mounted with the `noexec` option, so the execute permission bits on all files are ignored, and you cannot directly execute any program residing on this filesystem. Note that the `noexec` mount option is implied by the `user` option in `/etc/fstab` (supposedly for security reasons, even though unlike the `nodev` and `nosuid` options, `noexec` does not in fact provide any security). If you use `user` and want to have executable files, use `user,exec`.

It's also possible that the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line of the script points to a file that exists but isn't executable — in that case, [the error message confusingly refers to the script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53097/bin-sh-check-dependencies-pl-not-found-but-check-dependencies-pl-exists/53163#53163) even though the error is with the interpreter. However it's unlikely that the shebang would point to a wrong existing file (if the error was “not found”, a dangling shebang would be more plausible).