# Linux From Scratch: make no such file or directory, bad interpreter

Tags: executable, lfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting “Not found” message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)

I have finished the chapter 5 of the book.
And after I entered the chroot I realized that `make` is not working even though it is present.

```
root:/sources/linux-3.5.2# make mrproper
bash: /tools/bin/make: No such file or directory
```

the path is correct

```
echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin
```

AND

```
 ls -l /tools/bin/make
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 559139 Nov 13 11:19 /tools/bin/make
```

I read on LFS FAQ that is probably due to a bad interpreter ([link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/faq.html#any-no-such-file)) so I did

```
readelf -l /tools/bin/make | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

so it's wrong they said it should be something like **/tools/lib/ld-linux.so.2**

Is there a way to precise when building it the right interpreter ?

Thanks

Comment: *With the new Ch 5 build procedure, the most common cause of this problem is forgetting to apply the specs patch.*  Have you done this?

Comment: I did apply the patch of chatper 6.

Comment: And did the problem go away?

Comment: No nothing has changed