# Linux isn't sure whether a file exists or not

Tags: permissions, files, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting “Not found” message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)

```
ts3user@...:~/ts3$ dir
CHANGELOG
LICENSE
doc
...
ts3server.pid
ts3server_linux_x86
ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
ts3server_startscript.sh
tsdns 
ts3user@...:~/ts3$ ./ts3server_linux_x86
sh: ./ts3server_linux_x86: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, dir command reports existence of teamspeak executable. However, when I try to launch it, it states that the file does not exist. What is that? I did chmod 0777 to that directory and chomd 0755 to `ts3server_linux_x86`.

Comment: By the way, the *nix command is really `ls`, not `dir` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teamspeak has two server package:"Server amd64" or "Server x86"

You try to execute the 32 bits version, and I guess your linux is 64 bits.

Two solutions:

1. [download the 64 bits package](http://www.teamspeak.com/?page=downloads)
2. install the ia32 libs to be able to run 32 bits binaries:
   `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: Thank you, you vere absolutelly right. Now it's time to go to TS forums to find out, why i cannoct connect to the server using normal client. (telnet works just fine)

Comment: Its so unfortunate, but I need 2 more reputation to be able to vote up your post :(

Answer (score 0):

One (non-)obvious situation I can think of when something like this can happen, is if there is a non-printing character (e.g. a space) at the beginning or the end of the file name, but you fail to account for that in your command invocation. It would appear to be unlikely in this particular case, but has been known to bite people.

Try typing: `./*ts3server_linux_x86*` <kbd>tab</kbd> and see what that expands to. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> a second time if you don't get anything back (might be needed, depending on what you elided).

Comment: Nope, seems that the filename does not contait any spaces on beginning or the end.
It really is a little unlikely for software installer, but it surely was wort a try.