# How to run 32 bit programs on 64 bit Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, 64bit, android, 32bit

Although the Android Development Tools (ADT) bundle is available as a zip package for 'Linux 64 Bit' it [states following requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements):

> 64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications.

And indeed, just running the packaged eclipse on a Fedora 17 64 bit system results in errors, because it can't 'find' several development tools, e.g. `adb` or `aapt`:

> Error executing aapt: Cannot run program "/home/juser/local/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory: error=2, No such file or directory

The 'no such file' is misleading because it is there (under $HOME/local):

```
adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/aapt
```

But I can't execute it on the shell:

```
~/local $ ./adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/aapt 
zsh: no such file or directory: ./adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/aapt
```

Looking at the file

```
$ file adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/aapt
adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/aapt: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386,
 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8,
 not stripped
```

we see that it is a 32 binary. And it seems that my system (currently) is not capable of running 32-bit applications.

How do I change that? How do I make a current Fedora 64 bit system capable of running 32 bit applications?

(Of course one could also ask why someone ends up putting 32 bit binaries into a binary package called 'Linux 64 bit' ...)

Comment: Similar question with answer on AskFedora: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/365/how-do-i-install-32bit-libraries-on-a-64-bit

Comment: To understand why you're getting this message: [Getting “Not found” message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With regard to eclipse not being able to find `adb`, etc, this because without the 32-bit shared libraries needed to run them on the system, they are not executable.

With regard to 32-bit libraries, the situation is fairly simple: you just need to install the appropriate 32-bit libs.  On the 64-bit fedora 17 install I have here, the primary 64-bit libraries are in /usr/lib64 and optional 32-bit libs are in /usr/lib.  So, if I call `ldd` on on sdk/platform-tools/adb:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7791000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf776c000)
libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0xf7747000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf772d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7644000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7618000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf75fb000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7449000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7792000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf7444000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/libtinfo.so.5 (0xf7424000)
```

Notice these are all in /lib, which is a symlink to /usr/lib (not /usr/lib64).  Look:

```
»file /lib/libc.so.6
/lib/libc.so.6: symbolic link to `libc-2.15.so'
»file /lib/libc-2.15.so
/lib/libc-2.15.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object [...]
```

A 32-bit standard C library. What you can do is go through the 32-bit sdk tools and check to see what they are linked against with `ldd`.  I don't have an example at hand, but if something is missing `ldd` reports something like:

```
libc.so.6 => ??????
```

**First**, tho, for ldd to work you will need the 32-bit loader that comes with the 32-bit glibc (without this, ldd will call it a non-executable file and tell you nothing):

```
»yum search glibc
glibc.i686 : The GNU libc libraries
glibc.x86_64 : The GNU libc libraries
```

That's truncated, but the x86_64 package is what you have already; the i686 is the 32-bit version.  So just install that.

You do not need any of the 'devel' packages, as nothing gets compiled.  Beyond that, educated guesses and `yum whatprovides` / `yum search` should help (looking at the list for adb, there's also 32-bit versions of the C++ lib, ncurses, pthreads, and a I few things I don't know).

Quick tip about using `whatprovides`:

```
»yum whatprovides libtinfo
No matches found.
»yum whatprovides libtinfo.so.5
[2 matches]
»yum whatprovides "*/libtinfo.so.5"
[4 matches]
```

;)

Comment: ok, I'll try to install the i686 versions of libraries displayed via `ldd`. For the reason: I am not convinced, calling `file` on the bundle version of `adb` displays: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, **Intel 80386** - nothing to do with ARM emulation - and /usr/bin/adb (from the android-tools fedora package) is actually available as ELF 64-bit LSB executable, **x86-64**.

Comment: If I call ldd on `adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb` it displays 'not a dynamic executable'. Regarding the PATH - this is not the problem - fully specifying the path of e.g. `./adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb` in a terminal does not work (results in 'zsh: no such file or directory [..]').

Comment: Do you have glibc.i686 installed yet?  Like I said, you (likely) need a 32-bit loader for ldd to work, and that will be with the glibc package.  WRT adb being a 32-bit *intel* arch, that's because that's your system, something compiled for ARM will not work there.  However, the same 32-bit stuff *could* be compiled for ARM, and I imagine parts of it are when used on Android devices.  I admit might be wrong about that being the necessity, but in any case, that's what's available, and it is not really that much of a hassle.

Comment: WRT the path, maybe it is not necessary for eclipse, and (as you say) you may get the same error on the command line if the file cannot be executed anyway.  Just get the libs installed, etc, and you will find out.

Comment: yes, after installing `glibc.i686` ldd now displays useful information, I could thus install the needed library packages and the 32 bit tools are now executed without a problem.

Comment: There's no relation between the emulator being a 32-bit program and the emulated platform having a 32-bit processor. The Android emulator is in fact based on Qemu, which can emulate any of armv7 (32-bit), armv8 (64-bit), x86, amd64, mips, mips64, and many more, regardless of the host architecture.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Gilles.  I've fixed that and a few other little things in the post.

Answer (score 9):

You have to install the 32 bit glibc:

```
# yum install glibc.i686
```

This removes the misleading 'no such file or directory' message when trying to execute a 32 bit binary. With that the 64 bit Fedora system is capable of executing 32 bit binaries.

This also removes the misleading 'not a dynamic executable' message of `ldd` when calling `ldd` on a 32 bit dynamic executable.

Now you have to install missing 32 bit libraries the binaries under `adt-bundle-linux/sdk/platform-tools` are linked against:

```
# yum install zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 libgcc.i686
```

Thats it.

### Background

Some background how to derive the above package names. For example looking at the output of

```
$ ldd adb
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf774f000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf7725000)
libncurses.so.5 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf770b000)
libstdc++.so.6 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf76df000)
    [..]
```

means, that 2 libraries are still missing for adb.

For each 'not found' we have to lookup the package name, e.g.:

```
$ yum whatprovides '*libstdc++.so.6'
[..]
libstdc++-4.7.2-2.fc17.i686 : GNU Standard C++ Library
[..]
```

Now we take the package base name and add '.i686' to it to get the 32 bit version.

Comment: This answer is great, especially the first part - indeed installing `glibc.i686` allows `ldd` to work properly with i386 binaries.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the necessary package with:

```
sudo yum install redhat-lsb.i686
```