# "No such file or directory" on an executable, yet file exists and ldd reports all libraries present

Tags: linux, executable

So by any other command the executable file exists, yet when I try to execute it, it claims it is not there.

It is not a special character in the name because I renamed it though a "cat". And it seems to be a binary for the correct architecture... "seems", I guess the question is, what else throws tat error message BESIDES... the file not being there, because it obviously IS!

**ldd xls**

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77bc000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0xb6cc2000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb6c98000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xb6c8f000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xb6c76000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xb6c6d000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb6bd1000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb6b9b000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xb6b88000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb6a50000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb6a2a000)
    libQtSql.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtSql.so.4 (0xb69ea000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0xb6704000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb66ea000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xb66e7000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb65ea000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb6598000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb658f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6575000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb6571000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6485000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6468000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb6305000)
    libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0xb62ea000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xb62e4000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb62ba000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xb6297000)
    /lib/ld-lsb.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77bd000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb6258000)
    libffi.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.5 (0xb624f000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0xb61f1000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xb61ee000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb61e8000)
```

**uname -m** (Also, my distribution is Debian wheezy.)

```
i686
```

**file xls**

```
xls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), 
     dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15,
     BuildID[sha1]=0xa9786f61b371a683ae4306792f95e0636c288883, not stripped
```

**ls -ld xls**

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4634064 May 20 14:35 xls
```

**cat**

```
root@pc170:# cat xls > zls
root@pc170:# ./zls
-su: ./zls: Permission denied
root@pc170:# chmod +x zls
root@pc170:# ./zls
-su: ./zls: No such file or directory
```

**time**

```
root@pc170:# time ./zls
-su: ./zls: No such file or directory

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: What about `LD_DEBUG=all /lib/ld-lsb.so.3 ./zls`?

Comment: One thing about this: it says `"su: "` which makes it seem like you're executing a `system()` or something from inside the program and it's saying that after it does the `su` it can't find the executable in the directory it ends up in. What happens if you copy or symlink it to `/bin` or something?

Comment: Let's try `objdump -j .interp -s ./zls`. I suspect that will list the file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 24):

This does look like a [missing loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system). Short story: the dynamic loader expected by the program is missing, and the error messages are misleading in this case. Since I don't think I've discussed that before, let me explain the relevant part of the output of `ldd`. Most of it constists of lines of the form `library_soname => /path/to/library_file`.

```
/lib/ld-lsb.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77bd000)
```

Amongst the libraries, we see something that isn't a shared library: it's the program that loads the shared libraries. The program is requesting `/lib/ld-lsb.so.3`, but the kernel doesn't find it, so it reports “No such file or directory”. Yet `ldd` does find the loader, because `ldd` is a wrapper script that calls a hard-coded loader in a special environment, and the loader always reports its own path no matter what loader path the program has expected.

You have `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on your system, which is the *de facto* standard location for the ELF loader on x86_32 Linux systems. The program requires `/lib/ld-lsb.so.3`, which is the [*de jure* standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml) location.

Install your distribution's minimal LSB support, for example the `lsb-core` package on Debian. If your distribution doesn't have that (most do), create a symbolic link `/lib/ld-lsb.so.3 -> ld-linux.so.2`. In desperation you can call the loader explicitly: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./xls`.

Comment: Indeed, the loader is what that objdump line would have printed out. I forgot it was actually in the `ldd` output. Good catch!

Comment: This is exactly the problem I saw, with the misleading error message.  One issue is that 'ldd' won't run if the dynamic loader isn't present because it's (on centos at least) a shell script.

Comment: Thank you for this most helpful post among a sea of posts that talk about missing 32-bit libs on a 64-bit system.

Comment: `readelf -a  zls | grep "Requesting program interpreter"` will print the loader.