# chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory

Tags: executable, chroot

When I run the `chroot` command an error is given:

```
failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can the question be considered a pure duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76490/no-such-file-or-directory-on-an-executable-yet-file-exists-and-ldd-reports-al? The answers to the questions represent a possible solution for the problem definitely worth a link, but that doesn't make the question a duplicate of it.

Comment: The issue for me was that I was using a 32-bit Live CD to mount a 64-bit OS disk and chroot to it. A 32-bit kernel can't run 64-bit bash. The solution was to get a 64-bit Live CD. (The linked duplicate is entirely unrelated.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, despite the explanation of the source of the problem being applicable to both questions. The question this is marked a duplicate of is about missing libraries on a generic install, whereas this question is specifically about an error occurring in a chrooted environment.

Answer (score 51):

This error means that there is no `/bin/bash` directory **inside chroot**. Make sure you point it to where `bash` (or other shell's) executable is in `chroot` directory.

If you have `/mnt/somedir/usr/bin/bash` then execute `chroot /mnt/somedir /usr/bin/bash`.

Apart from the above, you also need to add `libc` directory dependencies, as mentioned in the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416556/37843).

Comment: There is a /bin/bash file in the rootfs folder

Comment: It might be caused by some failing command/line in `/root/.bashrc` or `/root/.bash_profile` in your `chroot`. Can you temporarily rename these files? Also can you make sure that `bash` is executable (`chmod +x /chroot/bin/bash`)?

Comment: aspade@home-ba:~/DebianArm$ sudo chmod +x rootfs/bin/bash.
aspade@home-ba:~/DebianArm$ sudo chroot rootfs.
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory

Comment: I have the same problem. I have bin/bash inside the folder I'm trying to chroot to, but it still tells me the same thing.

Comment: I figured it out. bin/bash is there, but I didn't have /lib and /lib64 inside it. /bin/bash depends (ofc) on libc, ld-linux, libdl etc... So simple cp -a /usr rootfs/, cp -a /lib rootfs/, cp -a /lib64 rootfs/ was enough. (You can mount-bind those ofc, but I copied them, because I want to run something dangerous, which might corrupt those files in rootfs.) The message from chroot could be more descriptive. "no such file or directory" really means "I can't run this sh...".

Comment: Doing mount-binds of those folders worked for me as well! I had originally done /usr and /lib but forgot /lib64 and was getting the same errors, but mount-binding /lib64 made it work. Thanks!

Comment: Like @Matt, I was missing `/lib64` in the chroot directory, and once I added it (and the symlinked .so file inside), everything worked fine. Thanks also to @Dalibor Filus for the notes above!

Comment: @DaliborFilus You should ad your comment as an answer! (IMHO) So people don't need to read through all the comments!!

Comment: You can run `ldd /bin/bash` to see the exact files bash depends on that have to be copied.

Answer (score 47):

I had `/bin/bash` inside chrooted directory, but I didn't have `/lib` and `/lib64` inside it. The message from `chroot` could be more descriptive. "no such file or directory" really means "I can't run this...".

`/bin/bash` depends of course on `libc`, `ld-linux`, `libdl` etc., you can use `ldd /bin/bash` to see which libraries it requires.

1. You can `mount -o bind` these directories under `chroot`
2. Or you can copy these libraries to `chroot`, if you don't trust the chrooted env to not corrupt them, like so:

   ```
   cp -a /usr rootfs/
   cp -a /lib rootfs/
   cp -a /lib64 rootfs/
   ```

Comment: this will create duplicates.. which is not optimized when we have lots of setups

Comment: This doesn't create duplicates if you use the first method (marked as 1)). The second one is useful if you chroot to untrusted environment. For example, you have a partition with a trojan or something.

Comment: I accidentally made my system unbootable when interrupted cp -a /usr /mnt

Comment: my "/lib" was not a symlink to `usr/lib`, it was actually a real folder! that happened after I tried to `checkinstall vmwareplayer` and it failed saying there was a new version installed. Then I guess that when checkinstall tried to revert the changes, it (or vmwareplayer installer) messed up /lib. That also caused a problem making ubuntu22.04 unbootable because /sbin/init or /etc/init not found.

Answer (score 10):

`chroot` tries to start the shell that is set in your `$SHELL` environment variable by default, but it looks for it in your new root dir, which seems not to contain `/bin/bash`, so it cannot start.

You can tell chroot to start another program inside the new root by simply adding it as a parameter:

```
chroot /your/new/root /bin/foo --options...
```

Note that the path of the command is interpreted *inside* your new root, so in this example the called program is in fact in `/your/new/root/bin/foo`

Comment: There is a /bin/bash file in the rootfs file so what is the problem

Answer (score 6):

In case you are doing a cross compilation you need to use qemu simulator which can run /mnt/somedir/bin/bash. Below are the steps for **armhf cross compilation.** Steps for other architectures should be similar.

1. First install qemu-user-static

**sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static**

2. Then copy the 'qemu-arm-static' binary into the chroot directory

**sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /mnt/usr/bin/**

Once you copy the qemu-arm-static into the /mnt/usr/bin you will be able to do chroot.

Check this out for more details: https://blog.lazy-evaluation.net/posts/linux/debian-armhf-bootstrap.html

Comment: There is no indication that this is what the user is trying to do.

Comment: The errors are same for both the cases. If someone who is doing cross compilation faces this issue, he can find the answer here.

Comment: That was actually my case, I created a rootfs for arm64 on a x86 and using `debootstrap` but in order for the chroot to work I had to run `qemu-debootstrap` which added 'usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static` under the rootfs. Somehow the chroot command is able to detect it and execute the bash inside the qemu

Comment: On an Ubuntu Jammy amd64 host, and Debian Unstable riscv64 chroot, I simply installed `qemu-user-static` on the host and it started working. No need to copy anything, which is nice.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error when trying to ssh to a chrooted account on a remote server. In my case, I was missing the following file in the remote lib64 directory. *Server is Centos6.9*

```
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

It was fixed by executing the following:

```
cp /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /secure/jail/lib64/
```

Comment: didn't fix it for me, but doing `cp -r /lib /lib64 /secure/jail` fixed it, i needed something from both lib and lib64, and i didn't bother to figure out exactly what. (probably because i had multiarch enabled)

Answer (score 2):

Make it sure /lib is a symlink to `usr/lib`.

In my case, in ubuntu 22.04, after I tried to checkinstall vmwareplayer, the `/lib` got messed up when it failed saying there was a new version installed. Then I guess that when checkinstall tried to revert the changes, it (or vmwareplayer installer) messed up /lib.

So the `/lib` was not a symlink to `usr/lib`, it was actually a real empty folder!

That also caused a serious problem making ubuntu22.04 unbootable because of /sbin/init or /etc/init not found: `run-init: can't execute '/sbin/init': No such file or directory` and `/etc/init permission denied`
It caused also kernel panic `attempted to kill init` on boot time.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me solve the problem on a rescue boot of elementary OS 7x. The /lib directory just had a some other folders in it terminfo/x/xterm-256color. I renamed, created the symlink as suggested and was able to chroot into my broken system and repair it.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut command to copy all the lib that's require by a command
for this example /bin/bash (You have to replace `{CHROOT PATH}` with the path of your chroot)

the file usually paste into `lib` `lib64` depends on the `/bin/bash` requirement

```
list="$(ldd /bin/bash | egrep -o '/lib.*\.[0-9]')"
for i in $list; do cp -v --parents "$i" "{CHROOT PATH}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the root has been changed the relative links to bash and other libraries no longer work. You need to copy those libraries into your `DIR_TO_CHROOT`

1. Copy bash

   ```
    mkdir /DIR_TO_CHROOT/bin
    cp /bin/bash /DIR_TO_CHROOT/bin # copy bash
   ```
2. Copy bash's dependencies

   - create `lib` and `lib64` to host these dependencies

     ```
     mkdir /DIR_TO_CHROOT/lib{,64} # create lib and lib64 folders
     ```
   - Find the exact dependencies needed (example output from my installation):

     ```
     ldd /bin/bash

     linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa89d8000)
     libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f6fb8a07000)
     libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6fb8803000)
     libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6fb8412000)
     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6fb8f4b000)
     ```
   - So *in my own case*, I copy the dependencies like this:

     ```
     cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /DIR_TO_CHROOT/lib #lib
     cp /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /DIR_TO_CHROOT/lib64 #lib64
     ```

Now you should be able to use bash

```
chroot /my-new-root bash
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error as well, but the solution turned out to be much simpler for me than many of the above answers. I was simply chroot'ing to the wrong directory.

On modern versions of the product my team supports, the product chroot is `/opt/productname`,
hence  we use `sudo chroot /opt/productname`.

On very old versions of the product, the product chroot is named `/opt/productname-x-y-z`. ie it has the version appended to the product chroot name.

So `sudo chroot /opt/productname` on the old system, gave me the `"chroot: command failed ... "` error. On the old system, `/opt/productname` existed, but was not actually a chroot directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was same problem **/bin/bash command not found**. I resolved it.

actually I am using ubuntu 22 in aarch64 architecture.
So I was doing a mistake that is by using lib64 folder in chroot directory but it was wrong I was need to use lib directory.

Because aarch64 usage lib not lib64.

```
mkdir -p /home/newroot
mkdir -p /home/newroot/{bin,lib}
cp /bin/bash /home/newroot/bin
ldd /bin/bash
```

Now you see some files path copy all path

```
cp path1 path2 path3 /home/newroot/lib
```

Now do other works your problem should be solved..

Answer (score 0):

you need to run ldd against bash `ldd $(which bash)`, then you might find a missing dependency, for example if you didn't mount/copy lib64, for 64 systems, it will through this error.

Answer (score 0):

Something no one has mentioned yet, if the goal is not to keep copies of libraries you locate with ldd. When you build busybox it respects `LDFLAGS=--static` per their [FAQ](https://busybox.net/FAQ.htm). This will build all necessary libraries into your binaries. This does increase the size of the binaries, but... you'd need most of this disk space to store what you're locating with ldd anyway.

Note that you may still need to copy your c library (libc.so.6), core math library (libm.so.6), namespace resolution library (libresolv.so.2), and kernel library (in my case, since I am using a raspberry pi, ld-linux-armhf.so.3) . You can use the ldd tool as directed in other answers on your static busybox binary to discover whether this is the case.

These may in turn depend on other libraries. To discover whether this is the case you can use the file tool. I am using the full path to raspberry pi's libm.so.6 as an example :

```
file /chroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6
```

In my case, since ARM processors need many libraries, I copied my entire arm-linux-gnueabihf folder into my lib folder, allowing me to access my chroot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `ldd /bin/bash` to see dependences. Wiil reply like follows:

> ```
> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd057eb000)
> libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f83183bc000)
> libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f83183b6000)
> libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f83181c4000)
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8318536000)
> ```

2. Then for each run `diff`. Like `diff /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6` etc. (Change `/mnt` to your mount path.)

   Also run diff for the bash, like `diff /usr/bin/bash /mnt/usr/bin/bash`.

   Skip `linux-vdso.so.1` because it inserted into kernel.
3. If will found differences then make replace these by files from Live CD.
4. Also check that the symlink links `/lib`, `/lib32`, `/lib64`  lead to the correct directories (to `/usr/lib` etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

After that, look for the user that gives you the problems and verify that in front of / bin / bash there are no spaces or any other character, in case of chroor, verify the root user.

nano can be replaced by any text editor.

Answer (score -1):

The bash `elf` is not available in `/bin`, `/usr/bin/` etc.

```
cp -rf --preserve=links  /usr/bin/* myroot/usr/bin/; cp --preserve=links  -rf /lib64/*  myroot/lib64/;..
```

copy all libraries and ELFs.