# arch linux installation base base-devel error could not open file invalid argument

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, chroot, pacman

I'm trying to install arch on my laptop. My `pacstrap -i /mnt base base-devel` fails to install one file and shows this error repeatedly:

```
error: could not open file /mnt/var/cache/pacman/
pkg/vi-1:070224-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.part: Invalid argument
```

and my `arch-chroot` wont work cause `no such file or dierctory`

I looked at earlier questions on this site like these:

[chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128046/chroot-failed-to-run-command-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory)

["No such file or directory" on an executable, yet file exists and ldd reports all libraries present](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76490/no-such-file-or-directory-on-an-executable-yet-file-exists-and-ldd-reports-al)

but a) my partition IS ext4
    b) i cant find bin/bash anywhere

So how do I install this package?
(i checked the directory `/mnt/var/cache/pacman/pkg/` and the vi file isnt there)

Comment: Try just pacstrapping base and then install the devel packages once inside the chroot

Comment: still same error

Comment: seems to be vi the editor

Comment: now im starting to think that isnt the reason i cant chroot.

Comment: maybe try deleting the files in /mnt/var/cache/paman/pkg

Comment: I'd have to reinstall them then?

Comment: No that directory is just for downloads

Comment: Everything that is installed will be kept installed

Comment: Apparently rebooting works. Sometimes.