# chroot: failed to run command -arch installation

Tags: linux, chroot

I am getting issue while chroot into arch installation after base installation.

```
 root@archiso ~ # arch-chroot /mnt
 chroot: failed to run command ./bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

However /bin/bash is there:

```
root@archiso ~ # ls /bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

Thanks

Comment: I have gone through below question: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128046/chroot-failed-to-run-command-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory.

Comment: `PATH='/bin/bash:$PATH'` then try `chroot`

Comment: After this it's saying 'Command not found: arch-chroot'

Comment: `/usr/bin/arch-chroot`

Comment: I never faced this issue. Follow this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide

Comment: Still the same issue, not able to figure out what is the issue

Comment: Download new iso and create bootable usb using `rufus` or `dd`

Comment: `/bin/bash` is in the root filesystem, but is it in the new root filesystem? `ls /mnt/bin/bash`? All shared libraries needed by bash also need to be present unde `/mnt`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Thanks for looking into it. I tried reinstalling by adding with new iso. It worked. I will have a look at the possible reason of this error some time later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arch-chroot by default calls chroot with the command /bin/bash. The command is run AFTER new root is set which means the root passed to arch-chroot must have a /bin/bash underneath it as /mnt/bin/bash.

You must have run pacstrap without specifying the base package.

```
pacstrap /mnt base
```

not something like

```
pacstrap /mnt base-dev
```

Comment: pacstrap defaults to base, so they would have to have really screwed up...

Comment: Oh, good point!