# Building mips package on amd64: Exec format error chroot: failed to run command 'mount'

Tags: package-management, dpkg, mips, multiarch

I'm trying to cross-build a Debian/Ubuntu package on a running amd64 system to mips arch. I've tried several methods, from pubilder to sbuild, but I keep failing. About the latter, on a freshly installed Debian 9 I do:

```bsh
apt-get -y install sbuild
sbuild-createchroot --arch=mips --make-sbuild-tarball=/srv/chroots/wheezy-sbuild.tgz wheezy /srv/chroots/wheezy http://archive.debian.org/debian/
```

But in the end I get:

```
W: Failure trying to run: chroot /srv/chroots/wheezy dpkg-deb -f /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.16.18_mips.deb Version
W: See /srv/chroots/wheezy/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details
W: Failure trying to run: chroot /srv/chroots/wheezy mount -t proc proc /proc
W: See /srv/chroots/wheezy/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details
E: Error running debootstrap at /usr/sbin/sbuild-createchroot line 268.
```

and the log contains:

```
chroot: failed to run command 'dpkg-deb': Exec format error
chroot: failed to run command 'mount': Exec format error
```

All the methods I tried end up with that *Exec format error* while trying different commands.

Comment: Do you have to target Wheezy? It would be much easier if you could target Stretch.

Comment: Yes, `wheezy`. I need to compile a package for UniFi Edge Router which is based on that version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-building only became nice and easy with Debian 9 as a target; it’s do-able with Debian 8 too, but targeting Debian 7 is a bit too complex. (EmDebian was dropped before Debian 7.)

There is however a simple setup to build `mipsel` Wheezy packages on any system capable of running QEMU, and building packages there will still be much faster than building on your router:

- start an `mipsel` setup in a `chroot` using `debootstrap`:

  ```
  sudo debootstrap --arch=mipsel --foreign --variant=buildd \
                   --include=fakeroot,build-essential \
                   wheezy ./wheezy-mipsel-chroot \
                   http://archive.debian.org/debian
  ```
- install QEMU and `binfmt_misc` support:

  ```
  sudo apt install qemu-user-static binfmt-support
  ```
- copy the QEMU binary into the `chroot`:

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-mipsel-static wheezy-mipsel-chroot/usr/bin
  ```

  (it’s statically-linked, so it will work fine)
- enter the chroot and finish `debootstrap`:

  ```
  sudo chroot wheezy-mipsel-chroot /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
  ```

You can now use your chroot to build packages. Manually, copy your package into the chroot, enter it, and build with `dpkg-buildpackage` after installing the build dependencies.

To build with `sbuild`, you’ll need to at least register the chroot with `schroot`; add a file named `/etc/schroot/chroot.d/wheezy-mipsel-sbuild` with the following contents:

```
[wheezy-mipsel-sbuild]
description=Debian wheezy/mipsel autobuilder
groups=root,sbuild
root-groups=root,sbuild
profile=sbuild
type=directory
directory=/usr/var/backups/steve/wheezy-mipsel-chroot
union-type=overlay
```

There are probably other steps required to get the chroot to work correctly with `sbuild`, in particular setting up the `sbuild` group inside the chroot and fixing ownership.

Comment: Before running the last commands I had to copy some dirs as stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416556/88439). But even if I can enter the chroot when running `debootstrap` package installation fails because `package architecture (mipsel) does not match system (amd64)`

Comment: You’ve destroyed the chroot by copying the directories. (The chroot contained foreign binaries which you overwrote with `amd64` binaries.) I ran all those commands before posting my answer, on a Debian 9 system, and it worked as described. (Although I realise now that I got the target arch wrong; I’ll run them again with `mipsel`...) What failed in your case, that led you to copy the directories?

Comment: I now have a working `mipsel` chroot after running the commands in my updated answer.

Comment: I've accepted the answer because all works. Unfortunately the chroot is not liked by sbuild. If I run `sbuild --dist=wheezy --host=mipsel -c /root/wheezy-mipsel-chroot/` I get `E: /root/wheezy-mipsel-chroot/: Chroot not found`

Comment: If you want to use the chroot with `sbuild` in its default `schroot` mode, you need to register it with `schroot`.

Comment: I found I need to run `sbuild-createchroot --arch=mipsel --setup-only  wheezy /root/wheezy-mipsel-chroot/ http://archive.debian.org/debian/` to prepare the chroot for sbuild, but still the same error

Comment: Yes, `sbuild-createchroot` doesn’t seem to cope with a completely foreign chroot; I couldn’t get it to work correctly. I’ll add the registration steps to my answer in a few minutes.