# Cannot login into SSH from non-admin account. /bin/bash: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, openssh, sftp

Although I have found many other posts on this exact problem, none of their presented solutions have fixed my issue.

I have configured and SFTP and SSH server on my raspberry pi. And ever since I enabled the SFTP server, **non-admin accounts cannot ssh into the raspberry pi anymore, being presented with this message:**

```
Last login: Sat Jul 15 12:02:42 2023 from 192.168.1.221
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Connection to xxx.yyy.z.vvv closed.
```

**I have followed the advice online** and created in my chroot directory *(see sshd_config file below)* a bin folder with the copied bash file inside it. However, nothing changed. I tried also adding the same folder into the home directory of the user I was trying to log in from, but once again - No change.

My knowledge of linux is way to limited to know where to go from there. I'll be happy to  recieve any advice as to what to troubleshoot next.

Thank You for your help.

***As mentioned above, the complete sshd_config file:*** *(My own configuration starts after the Subsystem line, I have not messed with anything above it)*

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems

#NIEAKTUALNE! \/
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

#O tak powinno byc :)
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

#===========================================================================
#                       POCZATEK RECZNEJ KONFIGURACJI
#===========================================================================

# Pozwol zalogowac sie tylko osobom z grupy tekkitboys
Match group tekkitboys
#Ustawienie Match group MUSI byc pierwszym ustawieniem SSH i SFTP!

#Dla bezpieczenstwa (nie wiem ale gosc zalecil)
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no

#Zaden uzytkownik SFTP nie bedzie wstanie wyjsc wyzej w strukturze plikow niz ten folder
ChrootDirectory /media
#Musialem dac az /media bo folder ten (z uwagi na bezpieczenstwo) musi miec root'a jako wlasciciela i
#grupy nie moga miec praw do zapisywania
```

Comment: In particular [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669188/100397) from that question

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. Thank You for your help.