# command "not found" even though it exists

Tags: shell, busybox, alpine-linux

I'm trying to run `/usr/local/bin/elm` using the `ash` shell provided by Busybox.

It exists, and it's executable:

```
$ stat /usr/local/bin/elm
  File: /usr/local/bin/elm
  Size: 19573124    Blocks: 38232      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 105h/261d   Inode: 8727197578  Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2021-06-14 19:09:57.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2020-04-24 18:06:57.000000000 +0000
Change: 2021-06-15 04:10:32.040437973 +0000
 Birth: -
```

But the shell doesn't care!

```bsh
$ /usr/local/bin/elm
sh: /usr/local/bin/elm: not found
```

`file /usr/local/bin/elm` shows

```
/usr/local/bin/elm: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=0a47662114da38e9a617def32f36be6c7c09dc64, not stripped
```

and `uname -a` gives

```
Linux dullbanana 4.20.69-ish iSH 1.2.1 (165) Jun  1 2021 00:45:30 i686 Linux
```

How do I run `/usr/local/bin/elm`?

Comment: Maybe relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166755/315749 - see also the Q/As linked from there.

Comment: Is `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` present on that system? What does `ls -lL /lib/ld-linux.so.2` say?

Comment: Also, what about `file /bin/ls` (or `file $(type ls | awk '{print $NF}')` if that first one fails)