# ldd shows library exists and is linked, program doesn't find it

Tags: sudo, libraries, dynamic-linking

Console Output:

```
bitnami@linux:~$ sudo svnmucc propset svn:needs-lock 1 file:///opt/bitnami/repositories/Standard/Ipc/trunk -m "test set"
svnmucc: error while loading shared libraries: libsvn_client-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
bitnami@linux:~$ ldd /opt/bitnami/subversion/bin/svnmucc
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffee8dfc000)
        libsvn_client-1.so.0 => /opt/bitnami/subversion/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.0 (0x00007f3d66102000)
        libsvn_wc-1.so.0 => /opt/bitnami/subversion/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so.0 (0x00007f3d65e30000)
        libsvn_ra-1.so.0 => /opt/bitnami/subversion/lib/libsvn_ra-1.so.0 (0x00007f3d65c22000)
        libsvn_diff-1.so.0 => /opt/bitnami/subversion/lib/libsvn_diff-1.so.0 (0x00007f3d65a09000)
```

I tried:

["No such file or directory" on an executable, yet file exists and ldd reports all libraries present](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76490/no-such-file-or-directory-on-an-executable-yet-file-exists-and-ldd-reports-al)

I installed:

```
lib32z1, lib32ncurses5, lib32bz2-1.0
```

I set:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/bitnami/subversion/lib:/opt/bitnami/sqlite/lib:/opt/bitnami/apache2/lib:/opt/bitnami/common/lib"
```

I am on a -

```
linux 3.13.0-55-generic #94-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- Bitnami SVN stack. So it is very likely that the Bitnami guys might have cranked something up. Fresh Debian/Arch/Ubuntu is not a solution (Company doesn't want something they can't pay for)

Q: How do I get further? It should have a 64bit 'lib-loader' installed since I am on a 64bit System. svnmucc is further provided by SVN itself, so it should have all libs necessary installed. I would figure that Bitnami somewhat tempered with the System, and now it doesn't have access to it (or something similar). Yet I haven't dealt much with libraries, which is why I am not very well funded in that topic.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux SE! [Take a tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with our philosophy, and edit your question to provide more information, as well as better formatting. Your console output should be posted in text format on this site. If you want to post image, I'd suggest posting it on site SE suggests. Also, rephrase your question - "What do" is not clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is it fine like this? Negative response is better than no response.

Comment: Could you try after doing: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/bitnami/subversion/lib` ? Is it working after that ?

Comment: i already set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/bitnami/subversion/lib:/opt/bitnami/sqlite/lib:/opt/bitnami/apache2/lib:/opt/bitnami/common/lib".
But good point, i'll add it to the Question.

Comment: It's better. Previous form could have lead to your question being closed, so I wanted to warn you. Unfortunately, I don't know how to help you.
You may try adding symlink to .so file in your directory, but that's not guaranteed to help(or even guaranteed to not help). Still, worth a try.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could set `LD_DEBUG=libs` in your environment and then running the command. This will trace the library search process.  You can set `LD_DEBUG=help` to see a list of available debugging options.

Comment: `sudo` tends to clear various environment variables to prevent e.g. some naughty user from loading in a malicious library and then hey presto full superuser access. Are you sure `sudo` isn't wiping `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` settings are dropped by `sudo` for the security.  To avoid being affected by that, you could add those paths to dynamic loader's global search path list.

Put the library path lines in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/bitnami.conf`:

```
/opt/bitnami/common/lib
/opt/bitnami/apache2/lib
/opt/bitnami/sqlite/lib
/opt/bitnami/subversion/lib
```

Then update `/etc/ld.so.cache` by the folowing command:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

See [ld.so](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/ld.so.8.html) and [ldconfig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ldconfig.8.html) manuals for details.