# Installing Maya 2014 : "./setup" returns "/Setup is a directory" instead of running installer?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

Im currently installing (or trying to install) my Autodesk 3d Packages on my new LinuxMint installation.

Im following the Guide for installing Autodesk Maya provided by Autodesk ([as found here](http://wikihelp.autodesk.com/Installation_Help/enu/2014/Help/0161-Product_161/0383-Maya383/0384-Maya_Ins384/0385-Maya_Ins385/0387-Install_387/0388-Install_388)), but I'm stuck at step 3:

- Type ./setup and press Enter.

Which returned this:

```
    gh057@JARVIS ~/Downloads/Maya_2014 $ su -
    Password: 
    JARVIS ~ # ./setup
    -su: ./setup: No such file or directory
    JARVIS ~ # cd /home/gh057/Downloads/Maya_2014
    JARVIS Maya_2014 # ./setup
    -su: ./setup: No such file or directory
    JARVIS Maya_2014 # ./Setup
    -su: ./Setup: Is a directory
    JARVIS Maya_2014 #
```

Comment: Is there a file called `setup` inside of the `Setup` directory?

Comment: There is a `Setup` directory (uppercase S) but apparently no file called `setup` (lowercase S). Does the file `setup` (lowercase S) actually exist? If so, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system. If not, it simply means that the instructions are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are not alone in running into difficulties installing Autodesk products on linux, as there are dozens of forums with people talking about their experiences.

It appears that the autodesk installation uses packages (.deb) files to help simplify the process.

Basically you need to extract the installation, and find the .deb files then run

```
sudo dpkg -i foo.deb
```

A guy named heath wrote a script to do exactly that.

https://gist.github.com/insomniacUNDERSCORElemon/5555214

**Update**
Make sure to install as root

```
sudo su -
apt-get install git
cd /tmp
git clone https://gist.github.com/5555214.git autodesk
cd autodesk
chmod +x maya_2014.sh
./maya_2014.sh
```

The installation will take a long time ( 30+ minutes), and appear to hang at times.

Comment: The script you posted appears to have syntax errors

Comment: I updated the answer with the steps I took to install it. When do you get the errors, and what errors are they?

Comment: I didn't run it, but `if [uname -m != x86_64]; then` is an obvious syntax error.

Comment: Thanks! At least i've got it installed now :) However, there's a new issue: 
`Start Maya Now?
yes
/usr/autodesk/maya2014-x64/bin/maya.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Also running it from the menu won't launch it. :/

Comment: This should solve the 'lib tiff.so.3' library error http://askubuntu.com/questions/44132/how-do-i-install-libtiff-so-3. See the answer by Lekensteyn or the answer by jahid65

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/lib/libtiff.so.3’: File exists
`
comes up when I run the command (i used the one for 64bit systems). executing maya via the menu link still does nothing :(

Comment: I would suggest running `ldconfig` or logging out and back in. Lastly try linking libtiff.so.4 to libtiff.so.3 `ln -s /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.4` and logging out and back in. If that still doesn't solve it, you may want to consider opening a new question.