# A file exists but executing it doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, java, executable

I downloaded a Java tarball, extracted the archive and copied over scp to a remote machine. Using the `ls` command, the java executable exists:

```
ubuntu@Ubuntu:~$ ls -la /home/ubuntu/jre1.7.0_55/bin/
total 420
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Mar 18 03:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu   4096 Apr 30 12:55 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu      8 Apr 30 10:58 ControlPanel -> jcontrol
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5714 Mar 18 03:53 java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  16246 Mar 18 03:54 java_vm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 104497 Mar 18 03:54 javaws
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   6391 Mar 18 03:54 jcontrol
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5873 Mar 18 03:53 keytool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   6013 Mar 18 03:53 orbd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5893 Mar 18 03:53 pack200
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5981 Mar 18 03:53 policytool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5865 Mar 18 03:53 rmid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5877 Mar 18 03:53 rmiregistry
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   5893 Mar 18 03:53 servertool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   6045 Mar 18 03:53 tnameserv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 215380 Mar 18 03:53 unpack200
```

However:

```
ubuntu@Ubuntu:~$ /home/ubuntu/jre1.7.0_55/bin/java
-bash: /home/ubuntu/jre1.7.0_55/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

What's the reason?

Comment: the second command you posted was ran on a different machine, `UbuntuSrpol`.  Verify that the directory `/home/ubunutu/jre1.7.0_55/bin/` exists on that machine.

Comment: Ok, there was a mistake in my question. It's fixed now - the problem still exists.

Comment: `ls -la /home/ubuntu/jre1.7.0_55/bin/java` also shows file details right?

Comment: Possibly that `java` uses a dynamic linker not available on your system. Run `readelf -p .interp that/java` to find which it is.

Comment: I have a feeling the OP may have been trying to run the command on the wrong machine or something similar...

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13409/20460

Comment: Are you sure the `java` binary is built for your architecture (also check 32/64-bit)? You can check your platform with `uname -io` and the binary using `file /home/ubuntu/jre1.7.0_55/bin/java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the (Java) binary you are executing ( which is 64 bit binary)  on 32 bit OS