# /init can't find /bin/mount, but find / can?

Tags: init-script, init

I have trouble, while booting up a linux machine of mine.

During the boot phase, while running the `/init` script it complains about not being able to find `mount`. My `PATH` variable is set to `/sbin` and `/bin`.

I tried calling `/bin/mount` directly, which also failed, saying it doesn't exist.

Then I included `find .`, which was found and showed that `/bin/mount` was actually accessible.

I'm not sure what to make of this. I read, that `initramfs` is basically a `busybox` shell, so could the problem lie there?

**UPDATE**

It seems like `mount` is the only command/file that does not get found. I started `sh` during the boot process; it tab completed mount and found it via `find`.

When I tried to execute it, however, I get the same "not found" error message as shown below.

**UPDATE 2**

I solved the problem temporarily by replacing every instance of `mount` in my `/init` with `/bin/busybox mount`. It works that way.

[image: Paused VM]

Comment: Check it with `ldd`.  It probably depends on a shared library that you are missing.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `coreutils`,`util-linux`, and `busybox`?

Comment: @psusi I checked. All libraries are, where they are expected.

Comment: @eyoung100 Yes, I did.

Comment: They are there inside the initramfs, or inside your normal system?

Comment: After answering psusi's question, do you have a tool that comes with the OS in the VM to rebuild the initrmfs, ie `mkinitrd`, or `genkernel` etc?

Comment: @eyoung100 I don't have those at my disposal unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have saved the script in DOS (windows) mode, meaning there is an extraneous return character at the end of each line.

Easiest way to fix that is probably to load the file in `vim`, change the mode with `:set notx` and then save the file, e.g. `:wq`.

Comment: Will test right away.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Weird. I assume you've already checked that `/bin/mount` has execute permission.

Comment: It had the sticky bit, but even after changing it, the shell wouldn't find it. But yes, I checked already.

Comment: I don't think the error message is consistent with spurious CR: `/bin/mount` would be called with arguments, so it's the last argument and not the command name that would have a CR at the end. Furthermore, the message would appear to be `: not found 15: /bin/mount` due to the CR in the message.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `/bin/mount` is a broken symbolic link. It would be found by `find .`, because that displays all directory entries, but if you try to run that program, it won't work since there's no file at the end of the rainbow. The BusyBox applet names would normally be links to the BusyBox executable: `mount -> busybox` or `mount -> /bin/busybox` (if `busybox` is in `/bin`).

Another possibility is that the `mount` binary is the one from your live system. That binary is a dynamically linked library that uses the dynamic loader, which may not be present in the initramfs. See [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system/13409#13409) for an explanation of a similar case.

Comment: I checked before, that `mount` is a file and not just a link. I'm not sure what you mean with live system. The one virtual box is running in, or the one from rootfs? I will look at the link, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Minix Live system where it was copied from into the initramfs.