# How to run 32bit executable on OpenSUSE 12.3 64bit?

Tags: opensuse, 64bit, 32bit

I am using OpenSUSE 12.3 64bit and have installed 32bit runtime environment from [here](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/opensuse/12.3/x86_64/patterns-openSUSE-32bit-12.3-7.10.1.x86_64.html). But when I enter command `./abc` which is a 32bit executable, it said "No such file or directory". What should I do?

Please note that I don't have internet connection on OpenSUSE. So if there are any additional packages required, please tell me the full name of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you poste the output of `ldd ./abc` please?

Comment: did you tab complete the execution? maybe there's a hidden character in the name.

Comment: @chaos It returned "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: @Fiximan That error message is the expected one if basic 32-bit support (specifically, the dynamic loader) is not present. See [a similar question about Debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system).

Comment: My executable suddenly works after I have installed gfortran. Any idea why would this happen?