# Cannot run 32-bit executable on 64-bit system with multi-arch support

Tags: dpkg, multiarch

I compiled a 32-bit executable for a Linux machine. It runs on most Linux distros without trouble. However, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I get the `No such file or directory` error when trying to execute it. The executable is present in the directory and has all the relevant permissions set.

There are a few answers detailing a solution to this ([like here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13409/117870)). So, I did:

1. `dpkg --print-architecture` prints `amd64`.
2. `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` prints `i386`.
   Even with multi-arch enabled by default, I am unable to get the executable to work.

What else do I need to install/do in order to get this executable to work?

P.S: The system does not have ia32-libs installed.

Comment: did you try running `ldd /path/to/your/32-bit/binary`?   your ubuntu 16.04 system is probably missing the 32-bit libraries that your program needs.  BTW, ia32-libs is obsolete, long replaced by multi-arch and simply installing the 32-bit versions of the libraries alongside the 64-bit version (e.g. `apt-get install libc6:i386`)

Comment: also, why not just recompile your program for amd64?  and make a `.deb` package while you're at it.

Comment: You may create a multiarch deb. http://askubuntu.com/questions/396030/how-do-i-create-a-multiarch-deb

Comment: @cas: Running `ldd pathToBinary` returns "not a dynamic executable". I could compile it against a 64-bit install too, but then it would require a lot more testing etc. and timelines are already very short. A multi-arch .deb package for a single executable? I might need to investigate that..

Comment: Also, internet access on the target systems cannot be presumed. If I install the .deb file, that means it will take the dependencies off the internet right?

Comment: What does `file pathToBinary` say?

Answer (score 2):

“No such file or directory” for a file that exists is a symptom of a [missing loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system). In your case, with a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system, you're missing the dynamic loader `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`.

Having multi-arch enabled means that you can install 32-bit packages on your 64-bit system. But to actually run 32-bit executables, you need to actually install 32-bit packages. At the very least, install [libc6:i386](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libc6); this is the package that contains the dynamic loader. Once you do that, you may still get errors refering to missing libraries, so install the requisite 32-bit library packages (`libFOO:i386`).