# No such file or directory error when trying to run an executable

Tags: bash, executable

I'm currently running Alpine Linux with XFCE. When I try to run an executable, in this case the "Tox" app .appimage file, like this

```
./qTox-v1.16.3.x86_64.AppImage
```

It returns this error

```
bash: ./qTox-v1.16.3.x86_64.AppImage: No such file or directory
```

despite the fact that the file exists and is in the directory that I'm in. What is going on here?

Comment: Are you on an x86-64 system? Try strace on it

Comment: Maybe related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282642/117549

Comment: What do `file qTox-v1.16.3.x86_64.AppImage` and `ls -ld qTox-v1.16.3.x86_64.AppImage` tell you?

Comment: That's because it cannot find its ELF interpreter. Run `readelf -a qTox-v1.16.3.x86_64.AppImage | grep interpreter`. If I'm not mistaken, Alpine Linux is based on the musl library (where the C library is _the interpreter_), and that program is probably linked against glibc (the GNU C library). I have no idea how that could work, other than installing glibc with its entire suite (including its dynamic linker / interpreter) one way or another. But I haven't any Alpine Linux to try on.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I had an app compiled and running on my 32 bit raspbian, and when I copied it to a 64 bit raspbian and set all the rights and permissions, I get exactly the error you describe. There are libraries I did not download the second time that I thought were only needed to compile, I'll work with it more tonoght, I just wanted you to know I've seen this error too.

Comment: update: installing all build tools and recompiling from source worked perfectly, going back to the original files still does not work.