# bash: ./idaq: No such file or directory

Tags: kali-linux, executable, x86, 32bit

```
$ uname -a
Linux kali 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5kali4 (2016-01-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    kali-rolling
Codename:   kali-rolling
```

Recently, I download IDA Demo from hex-rays website. After downloading and extracting it, I move to the directory contents it. But when I run ./idaq command. I received:

```
$ ./idaq
bash: ./idaq: No such file or directory
```

I tried to run this command

```
$ file ./idaq
./idaq: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, 
interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, 
BuildID[ha1]=2b4f4a30e791c6fa175a4d44c868ea9ac8f9d7da, stripped
```

Then I knew it is a 32-bit object file. After some Google search, I go to this page [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system?noredirect=1&lq=1), but these instructions don't help me anything.

My question is how I can run it.

P/s: My question is not elegent, if you don't like it, just press downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I think I must install `gcc-multilib` first by:

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable the `i386` architecture and install the appropriate libraries for IDA:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libpcre3:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libc6:i386 libffi6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libgcc1:i386 libxau6:i386 zlib1g:i386 libx11-6:i386
```

(Look at the output of `ldd idaq` and use `apt-file` to find packages providing the missing libraries.)