# How to make relocatable .deb package with maintainer scripts in it?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have a Debian package with postinst script in it that create symlinks. When I try to install the `.deb` package with `--root` (since I want to change the location where the package should be installed), I get this error:

```
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-installation script: No such file or directory
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

`dpkg` is trying to find the postinst script in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. What I can't understand is that according to the `dpkg` man page, using `--root` option changes the `admindir` to `newdir/var/lib/dpkg` as well.Then why is it trying to find postinst script in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`?

I tried creating another package that doesn't contain this maintainer script and installed it using the same `-i --root=newdir` option and that doesn't throw any error.

Please let me know how I can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg` did find the postinst script in `/your/root/var/lib/dpkg/info` — it tried to run it. It looks like the problem is a [missing loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system/13409#13409): `dpkg` finds the postinst script but then gets a “No such file or directory” error when it tries to execute it because the interpreter program for the script is not present (e.g. it's a Python script and `python-minimal` isn't installed). With an alternative instdir, the interpreter must be present under the instdir (dpkg chroots to the instdir before running package scripts).

If the interpreter isn't provided by a package tagged `Essential`, make sure that your package depends on the package that provides the interpreter.