# A bash/zsh script isn't getting invoked from a terminal in FreeBsd, neither in bash nor in zsh

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, freebsd

I have a script in FreeBsd 11

```
% cat my_script.sh 
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh

# [........]
```

It has `x` attribute:

```
-rwxr-xr--   1 root  wheel  669 Jun 14 02:45 my_script.sh
```

My shell is `zsh`. When I'm trying to execute it, I get an error. It has to do with the way I'm invoking it:

```
% sudo ./my_script.sh var1                  
sudo: ./my_script.sh: command not found


% sudo my_script.sh var1 
sudo: my_script.sh: command not found


% sudo source my_script.sh var1
sudo: source: command not found
```

What's the matter?

**update:**

I've changed my shell to bash, rebooted, changed the `#!` to bash and now I have:

```
$ sudo ./my_script.sh test9
sudo: ./my_script.sh: command not found
```

Comment: Pretty weird to have `x` permission for others, but not for the owner or group.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, typo

Comment: Is the filesystem it's located on mounted `noexec`?

Comment: Windows-style newlines?

Comment: Does it need root privileges to execute? Otherwise why use sudo? The environment for the root user is probably different, have you tried `sudo -E ./my_script.sh arg1`? A good practice when writing scripts that use programs and utilities in non-standard locations is to define the `PATH` environment in the script or use fully qualified paths to executables called.

Comment: Is it just this script, or is it all scripts?.  Have you tried running it while root (sudo su -)?  This should help narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: You would do well to edit the question to demonstrate that you do have the Z and Bourne Again shells even installed in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> % sudo ./my_script.sh var1                  
> sudo: ./my_script.sh: command not found
> ```

This message indicates that either the file `./my_script.sh` doesn't exist, or [its loader doesn't exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system/13409#13409). For a script, the loader is the executable mentioned in the [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Check that `/usr/local/bin/zsh` exists and that it isn't a broken symbolic link.

Check that the file really does contain `#!/usr/local/bin/zsh` as its first line and not, say `#!/usr/local/bin/zsh` with some whitespace or otherwise invisible characters after it or in the middle. Note in particular that a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) is one of the invisible characters that would break things. You would end up with a CR if you created (or perhaps if you edited) the script under Windows; if you edit scripts under Windows, make sure they're saved with line endings set to “LF” or “Unix” or “Linux” or whatever your editor calls it..

> ```
> % sudo my_script.sh var1 
> sudo: my_script.sh: command not found
> ```

This one doesn't work for a simple reason: `myscript.sh` is not in the [command search path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

> ```
> % sudo source my_script.sh var1
> sudo: source: command not found
> ```

This one doesn't work for a simple reason: `source` is a shell builtin, it isn't an executable. (It would make no sense as an executable since its purpose is to execute some shell code *in the current shell* — only a shell can do that.)

Which shell you're currently running is irrelevant for all three commands.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sudo` is neither guaranteed to maintain your current directory or your `PATH`.

Thus, to be sure scripts will be found, specify the complete path:

`sudo /path/to/my_script.sh`

The same error also appears for `sudo source` because `source` is a shell built-in, not a file. Instead of using a shell, `sudo` executes its arguments using `execev`, which expects a file.

For more information, see `man sudo` (particularly the **Process model** section and the **-E** and **-s** options), and for configuration options see `man sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers`.

For many more options about specifying the path to your script with `sudo`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo