# Running executable file: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, executable, cross-compilation

I am trying to run an executable file called `i686-elf-gcc` in my Kali Linux that I downloaded from [this repository](https://github.com/lordmilko/i686-elf-tools). It's a cross-compiler. The problem is that even though the terminal and a script that I wrote can both see that the file exists, when its time to actually execute it I get
`No such file or directory` error.Here is an image that explains it:

[image]

I have also to say that I have granted the necessary permissions to the executable.

Comment: Please paste the text instead of attaching a picture.

Comment: You are already logged in as `root`. Can you please explain me the reason for running the command with `sudo`?

Comment: For sure there is no `i386*` file.

Comment: Also the file you are executing and the file you are checking both are different

Comment: Also please check the executable bit for `i686-elf-gcc` file

Comment: Sorry guys, i am trying to fix this for about 2 hours now and i messed things up in the photo. Even when i typed "i686-elf-gcc" i got the same result: i686-elf-gcc: cannot open 'i686-elf-gcc' (No such file or directory). I just managed to fix it by installing libc6-i386 package(apt-get install libc6-i386). Thank you all of you for your help and sorry for the trouble !! I hope it may help anyone that ends up with the same problem trying to follow the OSDev tutorial.

Comment: It will help hardly anyone.  You've posted a non-indexable image instead of text, not given a correct description of the problem, handwaved over what you did to fix it, and not even supplied your answer as an actual answer.

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system). Also [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Typically, the "unable to execute... No such file or directory" means that either the executable binary itself **or one of the libraries it needs** does not exist. Libraries can also need other libraries themselves.

To see a list of libraries required by a specified executable or library, you can use the `ldd` command:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/i686-elf-gcc
```

If the resulting listing includes lines like

```
<library name> => not found
```

then the problem can be fixed by making sure the mentioned libraries are installed and in the library search path.

In this case, the libraries might be at `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/lib64`, but for some reason that directory is not included in the library search path.

If you want the extra libraries to be available for specific programs or sessions only, you could use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to identify the extra path(s) that should be searched for missing libraries. This will minimize the chance of conflicts with the system default libraries.

But if you want to add a library directory to the system default library search path, you should add it to `/etc/ld.so.conf` file, or create a `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` file of your choice and then run the `ldconfig` command as root to update the library search cache.

For example, if the missing libraries are found in `/usr/local/lib64` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory exists, you might want to create `crosscompiler.conf` file like this:

```
# echo "/usr/local/lib64" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/crosscompiler.conf
# ldconfig
```

Comment: “Unable to execute…” doesn't mean a missing library (you'd get the usual “cannot open shared object file” message after the executable starts). It means a missing loader. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Where is the duplicate question? @gilles-so-stop-being-evil