# Running a custom-compiled executable returns "No such file or directory"

Tags: dynamic-linking, assembly, ld, nasm

I have an executable but when I run it I get *"No such file or directory"*

```
$ chmod a+x bin 
$ file bin 
bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld64.so.1, not stripped
$ ./bin 
bash: ./bin: No such file or directory
```

Notice that this executable is in fact ELF 64-bit, as is the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because I forgot to include the `-dynamic-linker` options in the call to `ld`

```
-dynamic-linker /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Calling it as such,

```
ld -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o bin
```

makes it work fine.

For more information from a similar problem with 32-bit/64-bit mismatch see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)