# "No such file or directory" but the binary exist

Tags: bash, executable

I recently installed an dynamic binary translation program to run x86_64 binary on my ARMv8 server. After I uninstall the DBT tool, I found some weird error messages and it is very comfusing.

A little bit background information, using DBT tool, I am able to enter an bash (compiled for x86_64) and run tests just like on a x86_64 machine.

And the problem happens, after I finished my tests and decided to uninstall the program.

Occasionally, On the ARM server(where I have installed the DBT before using rpm packages), if I run a x86_64 statically linked `helloworld` binary, the output message is

```
-bash: ./helloworld: No such file or directory
```

But when I use `file` and `ls`, the binary existed.

```
file ./helloworld

./helloworld: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=465941947d84d055552ea628720b94096516c3a7, with debug_info, not stripped
```

However, to run the same binary on another ARM server that I did not installed the DBT tool before. The output message is

```
-bash: ./helloworld: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

The error message is what I want to receive since it points out the problem of unmatched binary clearly.

My concern is

**I might not completely uninstall the DBT tool but I can not find any leftovers after carefully examining the files that are added by the rpm packages.**

I have read posts such as https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists, and others.
They seems to run into the same problemsm but those information are not useful in my case.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: @terdon doesn't the same message sometimes indicate a problem with the loader - as for example [Getting “Not found” message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13409/65304)

Comment: yes, that's what the askubuntu q there also says. `execve()` also errors `ENOENT` if you have a script with a hashbang pointing to a nonexisting file. Similarly you could get a "Permission denied" if the _interpreter_ isn't executable, even if the script is. Though the case of a script, it looks like Bash opens the file itself to figure out what's going on and gives a better error message.

Comment: That's what the Linux manpage for `execve()` says too (and I'm assuming it's Linux, somehow): _"ENOENT The file filename or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist, or a shared library needed for the file or interpreter cannot be found."_, similar for `EACCES`. Though this one is a _static_ executable, so???

Comment: Post output of `readelf  -a ./helloworld | grep "program interpre"` (it can be empty) just to make sure that your copy of `file` isn't buggy.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk The `grep` command does not give any output. This happen for other x86_64 binary as well. I am using helloworld as the simplest example

Comment: @steeldriver well dang. Yes indeed. I hadn't known that and assumed that since the error was `bash: blah blah` the binary had never been launched. Thanks! And thank you Billy for the edit making it clear that the file does indeed exist.

Comment: Do the two servers have different contents in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The two servers are set up identically.