# Is it possible to copy a low-level utility like bash from one docker image to another?

Tags: bash, debian, docker

I feel like I am missing something fundamental to lower-level utilities like `bash` or `echo`.

I have a docker image (ImageA) that is missing a shell utility so it is nearly un-interactable and I need more flexibility from it. Let's assume I cannot recreate the image.

I know it is a Debian-bullseye distro and I assumed that I could just copy the `bash` binary from another basic Debian image (ImageB) using Docker multi-stage builds.

I've confirmed it exists in the /bin/ folder of ImageA but any attempts to execute it (or any utility for that matter) does not work with errors like: `/bin/bash: no such file or directory`.

Has anyone done anything like this and/or is this idea fundamentally flawed?

Comment: `ldd /bin/bash` will tell you the libraries that `bash` need in usual dynamic loading

Comment: Possibly related: [When you fail to execute a file that depends on a “loader”, the error you get may refer to the loader rather than the file you're executing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13409/108618).

Comment: Might be easier to copy the static-linked `busybox`, which will get you a decent shell and a bunch of utilities all in one file.