# Possible reasons for the shell's "not found" response?

Tags: shell, busybox, yocto

What are all the possible reasons that the shell would respond with "not found" when trying to run an executable?

- The executable definitely exists and has execute permission (`chmod +x`).
- `ldd` indicates that all dependencies are present.
- file indicates that the executable is compiled for the correct architecture (no reason why it shouldn't be, it's compiled along with the rest of the system in a Yocto build).

What other reasons could there be?

Comment: It depends what you put in the sh-bang,  `#! /path/to/bash` . Secondly  what does `type -a bash` tell you. Also what are the permissions on the bash executable? What does your `echo $SHELL` tell you?

Comment: "It depends what you put in the sh-bang, ```#! /path/to/bash```" - I'm not sure what this means - this is not part of a shell script, just at the terminal.
```type -a bash``` doesn't return anything (no error or other response).
```echo $SHELL``` returns ```/bin/sh```.
```ls -l /bin/sh``` returns ```lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            23 Mar  4  2024 /bin/sh -> /usr/bin/busybox.nosuid```.
Other executables work fine, it is just one in particular which is giving this problem.

Comment: As you can see, there is no `bash` installed in the system. I see this is a `busybox` system which for obvious reasons does not include bash.  So you are left to use `sh`.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami since the question mentions running `ldd`, this doesn’t seem to be a shell script.

Comment: Is the directory where the executable resides in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Thanks, yes correct this is sh rather than bash, I see that @Kusalananda has already corrected the question. @Kusalananda, yes the directory is in ```PATH``` (the executable is in ```/sbin```) - running the executable directly makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a binary with executable permissions, a common reason for “not found” error messages is that the dynamic loader requested by the binary doesn’t exist. You can check this using `readelf`:

```
$ readelf -l /path/to/binary | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

If that interpreter doesn’t exist, the executable will fail to run with a “not found” error. See [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13391/86440) for details.

Comment: This is interesting. ```readelf -l /sbin/ip.iproute2 | grep interpreter``` (```ip.iproute2``` is the executable in question) returns ```[Requesting program interpreter: /usr/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3]```. ```ls /usr/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3``` returns ```ls: /usr/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory```. ```ldd /sbin/ip.iproute2 | grep ld-linux-armhf.so.3``` returns ```/usr/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3```.  ```ls /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3``` indicates that the file is indeed present under ```/lib``` (not ```/usr/lib```).

Comment: I'm not sure what the ```=>``` in the ```ldd``` response means - I would have guessed symlink but there is none?

Comment: `=>` in `ldd`’s output indicates that the dependency on the left is resolved by the file on the right — but `ldd`’s resolver (the dynamic loader) is more sophisticated than the kernel’s ELF loader. If the interpreter doesn’t exist as it is named in the file, the kernel won’t load the executable, even if `ldd` is capable of resolving the interpreter.

Comment: I added a symlink which solved the problem. Next question is why the Yocto build is resulting in this issue, but that is beyond the scope of this immediate question (which is now answered, thank-you).