# command not found probably due to wrong names in symbolic links

Tags: ubuntu

I installed a software bundle from an ancient package. Now the binaries and libraries are in place, but I nevertheless get a command not found. My suspicion is that the binary calls something different and that the i686-linux part in the path just does not fit.

bin/i686-linux/

Is there a way to find out what is used on this system and what my call to the command is actually doing?

Maybe I can fix the problem by just using some additional symbolic links.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us: i) the _exact_ command you ran, ii) the _exact_ error message, and iii) how you installed whatever you installed. What is `bin/i686-linux/`? Do you mean `/bin/i686-linux/`? And why is this relevant? Please give us some context to understand what you did.

Comment: This may be relevant [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)

Comment: Yes, it was the 32bit problem. Thanks! I am sorry for the unspecific question. I installed the package yesterday and could not reproduce the error from installation.