# Why does sh say "not found" when it's definitely there?

Tags: embedded, router, command-not-found

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No such file or directory” lies on Optware installed binaries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/no-such-file-or-directory-lies-on-optware-installed-binaries)

I'm trying to add ebtables to a little router box. I went and got a binary compiled for the correct architecture, and put it on the box in `/sbin/`. When I do `/sbin/ebtables`, the shell says `/bin/sh: /sbin/ebtables: not found`, but I can do `ls -l /sbin/ebtables` and it shows up perfectly:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 admin    admin        4808 Aug  4 10:36 /sbin/ebtables
```

Any ideas about what's going on here?

Comment: you are logged in using admin ?

Comment: Yes, it's a single-user system. All the other commands also are owned by admin:admin, and I can run them just fine.

Comment: could be a 32 bits executable on 64 bits system. do "file your_exe_file"

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It could be a missing dependency. Notably you'll get that type of message if the runtime linker ("program interpreter") set in the `ELF` header does not exist on your system.

To check for that, run:

```
readelf -l your_executable|grep "program interpreter"
```

If what it gives you does not exist on your system, or has missing dependencies (check with `ldd`), you'll get that strange error message.

Demo:

```
$ gcc -o test t.c
$ readelf -l test|grep "program interpreter"
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
$ ./test
hello!

$ gcc -Wl,--dynamic-linker -Wl,/i/dont/exist.so -o test t.c
$ readelf -l test|grep "program interpreter"
      [Requesting program interpreter: /i/dont/exist.so]
$ ./test
bash: ./test: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That was the ticket: I needed a version compiled for uClibc. I compiled it myself and it worked fine.

Comment: `-ash: readelf: not found`, lol.

Comment: @nilskp: assuming you're also in an "embedded" situation, run readelf on your dev box (against the target binary). Otherwise, install it (binutils package usually).

Comment: Care to repost your answer to the original of this duplicate? I think your's is much more practical than the one here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11008/183837

Comment: `apk add --update binutils` in alpine linux

Answer (score -2):

Are you running it as `root`? IIRC some bash implementations refuse to run **anything** from `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` if you're not `root`.

I found [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-command-not-found) for an explanation (maybe not related, talks about OpenSUSE).

Comment: Yes, and I can run all the other programs in the directory with the exact same ownership and permissions just fine.

Comment: You've misunderstood the explanation on that link. It's about bash's behavior when a command is not found in the `$PATH`. If you give the full path to the command, bash will run it. Also, this wasn't likely to be relevant in the first place since a “little router box” is unlikely to be running bash.