# ld-uClibc.so missing

Tags: linux, executable, libraries, angstrom

I am trying to run an executable on Angstrom Linux, but ash tells me

```
-sh: ./myEx: not found
```

I've checked with readelf the program interpreter and it is

```
root@beagleboard:~# readelf -l myEx | grep interpreter
  [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0]
```

This program interpreter is missing. I've tried to symbolic link `ld-linux.so.3` to `ld-uClibc.so.0` but I think it's not correct and with no good results. I don't know where to install that or if I have to cross compile it from sources.

Comment: For background on interpreters, see ["No such file or directory" lies on Optware installed binaries](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11000)

Comment: Your program requires the dynamic loader from [uClibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UClibc), but your system is evidently based on Glibc or a compatible loader. You need to install uClibc. You can compile it from source. There's probably a better way to do that on Ångström, but I don't know how, and Google didn't turn up anything.

Comment: thanks.. probably my system is based on eglibc, now I'll try to build my executable for eglibc or install uclibc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out which libc my system was using. In my case it was `eglibc` that, cross compiling with openembedded for Angstrom 2012.05, is the default choice. Cross compiling for `eglibc` resolves this issue.

I wrote this next part only for reference, because I asked bitbake mailing list and I didn't found anything about this on Google:
to cross compile for `uclibc` set ANGSTROMLIBC = "uclibc" in a conf file (as stated on [this faq](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Uclibc_FAQ)). `uclibc` should not be compiled directly but it will be built when you run bitbake recipe on a source, and packaged under /tmp/deploy/ subdirectories, usually in the same directory of your package.