# File not found for file which is there

Tags: bash, executable, dynamic-linking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No such file or directory” lies on Optware installed binaries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/no-such-file-or-directory-lies-on-optware-installed-binaries)

I am currently trying to get some piece of hardware to work on an embedded device. One part of the driver is an executable, which has to be started to get the hardware to work. However when I try to execute it I get

```
bash: no such file or directory
```

I have checked and the file is definitely there, executable etc. I looked around online and I found that this could also be related to a problem between the architecture for which the file has been compiled and the one I am using. However I cannot find anything wrong. Here is some of the diagnostics I have run:

```
root@desktop:~# /usr/local/eGTouchARMwithX/eGTouchD
bash: /usr/local/eGTouchARMwithX/eGTouchD: No such file or directory
root@desktop:~# ls -l /usr/local/eGTouchARMwithX/eGTouchD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 198870 Jul 19 14:11 /usr/local/eGTouchARMwithX/eGTouchD
root@desktop:~# file /usr/local/eGTouchARMwithX/eGTouchD 
/usr/local/eGTouchARMwithX/eGTouchD: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped
root@desktop:~# uname -a
Linux desktop 3.2.0-1415-omap4 #20-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 18 19:03:59 UTC 2012 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
root@desktop:~# file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x1266f80916e3e59eb001459610510f5d05630297, stripped
root@desktop:~# ldd /usr/local/eGTouchARMwithX/eGTouchD
        not a dynamic executable
```

The only hint I have is that `file` reports this file as a dynamically linked executable, whereas `ldd` reports it as not being a dynamic executeable.

Any ideas what could be wrong with the file and how to fix this?

Comment: Is the partition mounted with executable permission?

Comment: @Marco: yes, the partition is mounted just fine. Other binaries on the same partition can be executed without any trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the architecture is the same, and this message commonly indicates that the binary is for a foreign architecture, the real meaning of this message is that it's linked against an incompatible C runtime library.

See [this message on the Linux From Scratch](http://archives.linuxfromscratch.org/mail-archives/lfs-support/2005-September/028323.html) website. In his case upgrading glibc gave him this error for several (but not all) commands.

You'll need to install the proper C runtime library that matches the binary or get a binary that matches your C runtime library.

Answer (score 2):

This can come from any mismatch in libc when using shared libraries (specifically the ld.so a.k.a dynamic loader)  Very common when using shared uclibc on a glibc box or vice versa.  I would recommend using a generic static toolchain until you get a working native shared one.  http://landley.net/aboriginal has a bootstrap toolchain for several architectures prebuilt.