# executable lies about own existence

Tags: ubuntu

Okay, I'm completely baffled on this one. I'm installing a piece of software called InterPro Scan for my superiors, and it is complaining about an executable not existing. Please see below.

```
root@cpt:/usr/local/lib/iprscan# bin/Linux/seqret 
bash: bin/Linux/seqret: No such file or directory
root@cpt:/usr/local/lib/iprscan# ls bin/Linux/seqret 
bin/Linux/seqret
root@cpt:/usr/local/lib/iprscan# stat bin/Linux/seqret 
  File: `bin/Linux/seqret'
  Size: 949624          Blocks: 1856       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 38541532    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1257/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1055/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2013-06-17 17:28:41.317364148 -0500
Modify: 2009-12-16 05:57:46.000000000 -0600
Change: 2013-06-17 17:28:33.049363860 -0500
 Birth: -
root@cpt:/usr/local/lib/iprscan# md5sum bin/Linux/seqret 
bc08e679fb146bc47e6f41636dcc1f88  bin/Linux/seqret
root@cpt:/usr/local/lib/iprscan# file /usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin/binaries/seqret

/usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin/binaries/seqret: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped
```

It exists! But it says it doesn't? I'm incredibly confused.

```
root@cpt:/usr/local/lib/iprscan# /usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin/iprscan -cli -i /usr/local/lib/iprscan/test.seq -o /usr/local/lib/iprscan/test.out -format raw -goterms -iprlookup
```

This calls the wrapper script:

```
/usr/local/lib/iprscan/conf/seqret.sh: line 18: /usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin/binaries/seqret: No such file or directory
/usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin/iprscan: checkParams: unable to create input files: formatSequences:
```

This is the original call to the wrapper script:

```
/usr/local/lib/iprscan/conf/seqret.sh  /usr/local/lib/iprscan/tmp/20130617/iprscan-20130617-17561022/iprscan-20130617-17561022.seqs > /usr/local/lib/iprscan/tmp/20130617/iprscan-20130617-17561022/iprscan-20130617-17561022.input.formatted: exit status 127
```

All of the input files exist.

The wrapper script itself

```
root@cpt:/usr/local/lib/iprscan# cat /usr/local/lib/iprscan/conf/seqret.sh
#!/bin/bash

##### NOTE ####
# Should be already set by iprscan_wrapper.pl.
# If not just add the full path to your iprscan installation
#IPRSCAN_HOME=/your/path/here/to/iprscan
###############
IPRSCAN_HOME=/usr/local/lib/iprscan

#Needed for seqret & sixpack emboss applications
EMBOSS_ROOT=$IPRSCAN_HOME/conf
export EMBOSS_ROOT

EMBOSS_ACDROOT=$IPRSCAN_HOME/conf/acd
export EMBOSS_ACDROOT

# "$@" is related to the command line of formatcmd tag in file iprscan.conf.
$IPRSCAN_HOME/bin/binaries/seqret -osf fasta -auto -stdout "$@"
```

Comment: Common mistake, it's probably a script and the first line to the interpretor is missing or something similar, sometimes if the line ends with a ^M you get this too.

Comment: Doesn't look like it... I'm adding the wrapper script for reference.

Comment: @EightBitTony a bad interpreter path error is usually shown as something else. [For example](https://dpaste.de/5rVck/)

Comment: @JoelDavis, a bash script calls an executable, which complains about itself not existing.

Comment: What does file /usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin/binaries/seqret return.

Comment: If my answer on the duplicate question doesn't solve your problem: what does `file bin/Linux/seqret` say? and `uname -m` and `ldd bin/Linux/seqret`?

Comment: `root@cpt:/usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin# /usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin/binaries/seqret
bash: /usr/local/lib/iprscan/bin/binaries/seqret: No such file or directory
`

Answer (score 1):

Based on evidence that stackexhcange poped up with after I'd posted my question, I'm guessing that this will be the cause of the problem. I'm installing 32 bit libraries now.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11008/22785
- [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)