# Getting an " Exec format error" on arm64 embedded Linux

Tags: ssh, arm64

I have a renesas v3h ARM v8 processor on an embedded platform. The yocto Linux on it doesnt have support for `sshd` so I was trying to install the binary in the rootfs. I downloaded the binary from [here](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/openssh) and copied it in the rootfs. When I try to run it, I get this error

```
root@v3h:/usr/bin# sshd
-sh: /usr/bin/sshd: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

To be sure that the binary is infact for an arm64, I did this -

```
readelf -h sshd
```

and the output is this -

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
```

Here are the permissions for ssh and sshd. `ssh` btw works fine.

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            23 Jan 28 11:27 ssh -> /usr/sbin/dropbearmulti
-rwxrwxr-x    1 1000     1000       2734032 Apr  2  2019 sshd
```

How do I resolve this?

Edit:

kernel information-

```
root@v3h:/usr/bin# uname -a
Linux v3h-p708 4.9.0-yocto-standard #7 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 28 13:14:31 MSK 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What is the `readelf` output for some other binary that _does_ work on your system?

Comment: What's the output of `file /usr/bin/sshd` and `ldd /usr/bin/sshd`? I suspect something's wrong with the loader (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/no-such-file-or-directory-lies-on-optware-installed-binaries/11008#11008 for explanations), although I don't know why this would result in ENOEXEC rather than ENOENT. Taking a binary from another distribution doesn't always work, if they use different libc or configure it differently. Try `sshd` from Yocto or OpenEmbedded.

Comment: Everythig is the same except the type: 

`readelf -h candump
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)`

Comment: `file: command not found`


`ldd /usr/bin/sshd
        not a dynamic executable`

Comment: And, even with your processor being an v3h Arm v8, what is the version of the Kernel you are using? Could you please provide the results of `uname -a` at the question? You will not be able to run a v8 binary if you are using a generic 32bits Arm Kernel...

Comment: @nwildner I just added the `uname-a` information.

Comment: @ Kusalananda, do you think the `Type` value difference in the two is the culprit? A search for the same doesnt seem to indicate that.