# Is an Intel 80386 application compatible with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU?

Tags: virtualbox, intel, compatibility, cpu-architecture

When I run my application:

```
./a.out
bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

and

```
bash ./a.out
./a.out: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file
```

I start feeling this is an architecture issue.

The file architecture:

```
file ./a.out
./a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1ddfecde2ce3df37f6fe3b30f1abc853dc3a9f74, with debug_info, not stripped
```

The virtual machine architecture:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 158
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
stepping    : 9
cpu MHz     : 2904.004
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti fsgsbase avx2 invpcid rdseed clflushopt md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 5808.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

The operating system:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOSStream
Description:    CentOS Stream release 8
Release:    8
Codename:   n/a
```

and

```
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-305.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 18 14:52:12 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

Can you please verify this is an architecture incompatibility?

If yes, how to get around this problem?

Comment: You need to install 32-bit support. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system for explanations and Debian instructions. I don't know what the corresponding instructions are for CentOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No such file or directory" lies on Optware installed binaries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/no-such-file-or-directory-lies-on-optware-installed-binaries)

Answer (score 0):

The worked solution for me

```
sudo dnf upgrade --allowerasing --best
sudo yum  -y install glibc.i686
sudo yum install libstdc++.i686
```